# Update Eclipse with Android development tools v. 23

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt

I updated Eclipse with the new SDK tools (rev. 23), but now when Eclipse starts I receive the error:

> This Android SDK requires Android Developer Toolkit version 23.0.0 or above. Current version is 22.6.3.v201404151837-1123206. Please update ADT to the latest version.

No updates were found with **"Check for updates"**. If I try **"Install new software"**, I can see version 23, but I can't upgrade due to the following error:

```
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
Software being installed: Android Development Tools 23.0.0.1245622 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.feature.group 23.0.0.1245622)
Software currently installed: Android Developer Tools 22.2.1.v201309180102-833290 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product 22.2.1.v201309180102-833290)
Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    ADT Package 22.6.3.v201404151837-1123206 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package 22.6.3.v201404151837-1123206)
    ADT Package 23.0.0.1245622 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package 23.0.0.1245622)
Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Android Development Tools 23.0.0.1245622 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.feature.group 23.0.0.1245622)
    To: com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package [23.0.0.1245622]
Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Android Development Tools 22.6.3.v201404151837-1123206 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 22.6.3.v201404151837-1123206)
    To: com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package [22.6.3.v201404151837-1123206]
Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: ADT Package 22.2.1.v201309180102-833290 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.feature.group 22.2.1.v201309180102-833290)
    To: com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 22.2.0
Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Android Developer Tools 22.2.1.v201309180102-833290 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product 22.2.1.v201309180102-833290)
    To: com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.feature.group [22.2.1.v201309180102-833290]
```

After download of the last ADT from the web site, it seems there's another problem.

With SDK Tools rev. 23 proguard is not installed, the folder SDK `dir/tools/proguard` is missing, and other tools are missing. This version contains several bugs.

Comment: @kaushik your comment is out of scope. I said that I've already tried to update Eclipse without luck.

Comment: I tried to remove plugins manually, but unable to remove "Android Developer Tools" - it wants to delete eclipse.exe file.

Comment: @joshas I can confirm. The only way seems to reinstall everything :(

Comment: I currently downloaded new ADT bundle (adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140624.zip). While it has some new issues, at least ADT works.

Comment: @joshas have you got proguard under sdk/tools/?

Comment: @greywolf82 No, proguard is not in sdk/tools on new bundle. The new ADT Bundle 20140624 seems to be buggy as well.

Comment: @joshas Dohhhh! It's really impossible.....

Comment: Re proguard, it's been raised as an issue - https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=72419

Comment: The missing Proguard isn't really an issue. Just download it from the Proguard site and extract the content into tools/proguard.

Comment: @EmanuelMoecklin I downloaded Proguard and I renamed proguard.android.txt but I receive errors, can you share your config file?

Comment: Is there a way I can revert my current updates ?

Comment: I think it needs to be renamed proguard.project.txt I could be wrong. I found a proguard file in \sdk\tools\lib. I was also told that's where annotations.jar was moved accidently but I can't find it. I just took that file from my work PC with v22 build tools (thank god).

Comment: @RED_ I renamed the file template found in Proguard configuration folder (I downloaded from proguard site) but it doesn't work, it gives to me some error due to some statement at the start of the file like -initjars

Comment: @r.bhardwaj see the answer I posted

Comment: @alvaro.delaserna: I would love to try it but unfortunately my eclipse executable was deleted when I have tried uninstalling "already installed" files as per answer posted by Biljana below.

Comment: I have got things working on my Ubuntu installation. I've explained here how : http://stackoverflow.com/a/24450781/243709

Comment: @r.bhardwaj if you go to Help>About Eclipse>Installation details you can then check out Installation History and revert any changes. It will only work if they were updates. If you uninstalled ADT to install the previous one, it won't work. If it did it as an update, you should be able to revert back.

Comment: Is there a working solution? None of the answers below are working for me, and in fact it broke my eclipse.

Comment: @VishwaIyer No IMHO. See my answer, we have to wait the fix.

Comment: The SDK Manager now has v23.0.1 of the Android SDK Tools, but this doesn't fix anything for me.  Not sure what's going on.

Comment: just because of the Android team lack of focus on ADT rather than Studio.

Comment: I wrote a short blog post about how to fix the issue in the most general sense because some can upgrade with problems and some just can't http://android-know-how-to.blogspot.co.il/2014/06/upgrading-to-adt-23-multiple-issues.html

Comment: Google Bug tracker : http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=72419#c12

Comment: One update and they mess everything up. Just unbelievable. They also ruined admob with google play services update. Nightmare for android devs.

Comment: Ugh, what a mess.  The download link Google provided now doesn't even extract properly.  "Error 0x80010135: Path too long" on pom.properties.  Booo.  :-(

Comment: The only thing that worked was a fresh a fresh download of adt bundle. I replaced the older eclipse folder and merged and overwrote the sdk folder. Worked!

Comment: RED_'s comment helped. I uninstalled the older 22 version and then I was able to upgrade.

Comment: What i did is downloaded new ADT (https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) and then used the same workspace which i used for previous one and then it all works for me.... no hassles no troubles all goes pretty well ...

Comment: @Dastagir hope that works.  I botched my enviornment today.

Comment: Download new Version of eclipse.

Answer (score 115, accepted):

[Google response](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=72419):

**This is a packaging bug. The entire proguard file is missing. We'll have an update asap, but until then just copy it over from a previous version of the tools:**

- http://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r22.6.2-linux.tgz
- http://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r22.6.2-windows.zip
- http://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r22.6.2-macosx.zip

and copy over the following files:

- tools/hprof-conv
- tools/support/annotations.jar
- tools/proguard

So at the end if you started from a new ADT copy by hand the files :)

**Edit:** with the latest ADT release, the bundle should now work with auto-update, so **install these new versions**:

- linux 64 bit vm: http://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140702.zip
- linux 32 bit vm: http://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-linux-x86-20140702.zip
- mac: http://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702.zip
- win32: http://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140702.zip
- win64: http://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702.zip

**Don't try to upgrade from previous version** because it doesn’t work at all.
If you have got problems with zipalign, it's now under build-tools and no more under tools/ so you can do a symbolic link or just copy it into the expected folder.

Comment: Under tools/support for annotations.jar, under tools/ for the whole proguard folder and under tools/ for the file hprof-conv

Comment: its not just 'proguard' . I installed ADT 23 and CLI ant build type 'debug' broken with 'missing zipalign'... 
 Cannot run program "/usr/local/src/android-sdk-linux/tools/zipalign": error=2, No such file or directory

Comment: @RobertRowntree Yes, I know. Even sqlite3 command is missing. I rellay hope Google can fix this mess asap.

Comment: i will completely remove ADT 23 and completely remove the new eclipse luna. i was fine on eclipse 4.4 RC4 and the upgrd to the release version seems to have broken everything. NDK prevents me from moving to  A-Studio..

Comment: This did work for me, But before doing this I had to uninstall Android SDK Tools-23, and paste complete tools folder.

Comment: yes, latest version released of ADT 20140702 works like a charm! :)

Comment: @Evilripper How'd you get ADT20140702 to extract?  I'm getting failures extracting pom.properties "path too long".

Comment: @BrianKnoblauch there is a stupid bug in windows (path too long) you must extract all to c:\a https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=72539#c9

Comment: OK, cool.  Ignore Google's instructions to extract to dev path, and just throw it on root without allowing subfolder.  Worked!  Thanks!

Comment: This 'answer' (workaround) works if you want to downgrade from Eclipse Kepler or later to Eclipse Juno which is what is included in the second set of zip files. Not sure if I can safely upgrade to Kepler or not now.

Comment: Dpwnload failed at the end while installing adt bundle 64 windows

Comment: ADT Download failed at the end for linux 64 bit. And the replacing tools folder also not at all work.

Comment: this is so stupid ...did they check their release????? when in the world will their Studio move out of Beta??!!?!?

Comment: zipalign is actually in the android-sdk-linux/build-tools/xx.x.x/ directory where xx.x.x is the Build Tools version e.g. 20.0.0

Comment: New version is available or not now?

Comment: @ツPratikButaniツ Since is now out Android Studio 1.0 I think ADT is now no more supported, I suggest you to migrate to Android Studio.

Comment: @greywolf82 But Android Studio is still now in Beta Version? Only one project handles at a time. Then....

Comment: @ツPratikButaniツ No Android Studio is now out with a stable version after 18 months of development and if I well remember the ADT is missing now in the download page, the message from Google is: Please use Android Studio :)

Answer (score 193):

Google has released ADT v23.0.2. This solved many problems of previous ADT version 23.

Step-by-step:

- Menu Help → Install New Software...
- For "Work with", select the Android source `https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse`
  [image: Work with Android source]
- Tick ADT v23.0 for installation, then click "Next"
- Eclipse will show "Install Remediation Page" since there is conflict with previous version. (If it does not, see below.) Select "Update my installation to be compatible with items being installed" to uninstall the old version and install the new one. After that, proceed with the usual steps.

[image: Install remediation page]

Note: When I installed the new version of ADT, I didn't include the new version of "Android Native Development Tools" package. Instead, I installed the rest of packages first, and then installed "Android Native Development Tools". For a reason, if I try to install all the new packages including "Android Native Development Tools", the installation fails.

If there is no "Remediation page", [the only way to remove the ADT plugin from Eclipse is to go to menu *Help* → *About Eclipse* → *Installation Details* and uninstall from there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9097282/755804). But there is a risk of uninstalling Eclipse itself.

Comment: I'm actually getting an error message with "conflicting dependency" instead of Eclipse saying it will uninstall the version 22.X.

Comment: Yep. Same thing. I'm installing Eclipse again with a new and fresh ADT bundle from Android web site.

Comment: When I tried to manually uninstall version 22.X eclipse seemed to disappear. Trying out with a new and fresh ADT bundle as well.

Comment: @Daniel Diaz have you got proguard under tools/?

Comment: @greywolf82 Under android skd tools folder? At android SDK folder tools I have many files, and at tools -> lib I have proguard-project.txt

Comment: When I installed the new version of ADT, I don't install the new version of "android native developed tools" package the first time. I've installed the other packages first, and next, I installed "android native developed tools". I don't know the reason, but if I try to install all the new packages with "android native developed tools" the installation fails

Comment: @DanielDíaz You have to have SDKDIR/tools/proguard folder. But I can say now that SDK tools rev 23 are buggy and proguard is not installed at all.

Comment: @greywolf82 - you are correct, proguard is completely missing.

Comment: @NickT I'm trying to install it by hand but I've got several errors

Comment: For some reason I didn't get any alternate solutions when trying this...just errors / conflicts.

Comment: Not happy with google right now, I don't like the burden of trying to solve these problems that shouldn't even exist.

Comment: @TylerPfaff me too bro , same error . finally i retrieve back my old ADT  :(

Comment: please uncheck show only the latest version..... after that i get version 23.0 and finally i got above screen.

Comment: From what I can tell, Google has moved to using Tycho to build the p2 repository instead of using the old pre-p2 way of generating the update site.  In the past if you hit that url with site.xml it would retun you the xml file.  A p2 repository is generated differently and isn't compatible with the old site.xml.  Which is why you are seeing the current issues and why eclipse has to jump through some hoops to update.  It is a pain, but it is better long term.

Comment: @kingargyle ok but it's not possible to create this kind of mess, breaking the development and without any clear advice......no it's not possible

Comment: It's worth noting, as I haven't seen it commented yet, be sure you change the radio button to the Update option. Mine was initially left on Keep installation the same and it was only going to update the native development tools.

Comment: @DanielDíaz I didn't get your 2nd point nor 3rd point, Also I don't see the screen You displayed ????

Comment: @vwvwvwvwvwvwvwvwvw At available software, at "Work with" listbox you need to select android source (https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse)

Comment: @DanielDíaz I followed your answer, but on Install Remediation Page, no matter which radio button I select, the Next button is greyed out.  Any ideas? I tried other suggestions in comments with no effect.

Comment: I have updated to 23.0.2 SDK, but I still get error message "This Android SDK requires Android Developer Toolkit version 23.0.0 or above". But I still can't get upodate. Eclise says there is no update if I run Help -> Seach for updates. If I run Help -> Install new software, it dos not let me install it, but I get this conflict error message for all componet.

Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: Android Traceview 23.0.2.1259578 (com.android.ide.eclipse.traceview.feature.feature.group 23.0.2.1259578) ...

Comment: Does not work, even leaving out the specified package.  What a mess.  Reason #34210987 I've turned from an Eclipse lover to an Eclipse hater.

Comment: Delete all the ADT tools (basically every installed module with the 23.xxx version number) and reinstalled ADT.  Life is good!  Module updates suck.  Delete, restart, all nice again!

Comment: I waited till October hoping this would go smoothly.  It didn't.

Comment: thanks uninstalling ADT tools 22 then installing 23 worked for me on Linux

Comment: this solution did not work for me, the google response below was successful. (reinstall..)

Comment: The bug is still there. Google did not fix anything, perhaps, intentionally, because they want the people move to Android Studio. Uninstalling previous version (from About Eclipse dialog) and Installing new version of ADT (as usual - Install New Software) worked for me. It's important to answer "Not now" to Eclipse when it asks for restart after uninstall and start installation right away.

Answer (score 53):

None of the other answers worked for me using the ADT bundle published on developer.android.com.

I ended up downloading the latest version of Eclipse (**not the ADT bundle**) and then installing the ADT plugin via menu *Help* → *Install new software* → entering `https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse` (mentioned by @RED_).

I also had to update my workspace to point to my previous workspace, and most things seemed to be restored.

On a side note: This seems like a good time to migrate to Android Studio...

Comment: So they're going to force the developers like this, to move to Studio?

Comment: I did the same.. it won't work for ADT bundle provided by developer.android.com and uninstalling ADT is not the solution

Comment: This worked for me too! But for some reason when downloading ADT it took a loooooooong time (download speed was 20kb/s and there is nothing wrong with my internet connection) :S Anyone also experienced that?

Comment: This solution only works with [Eclipse Juno](http://www.eclipse.org/juno/) for me. I also had to download the [stand-alone SDK tools](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html?pkg=tools) in addition to the ADT.

Comment: Yes, because exlipse claims, that sdk version 23 needs version 23 adt and eclipse shows that there is no updates available for eclipse adt, updates to ndk won't fix this problem, never. I had to install new version of Android Developing Tools. I used ADT bundle for linux 64 bit and unzipped it to new place than original one and installed all tools again as Andoide developer page guides us. In linux bundle SDK is still broken, so you must copy annotations.jar to right place as explained here. Whole story in explained in my answer. I coulkd save my old workspace and nothing was lost, huh.

Comment: But would I trust Android Studio, if this is how they handle things?

Comment: I was able to recover my Luna installation by just using the new software install (selected everything) and doing a clean rebuild of my Android projects.  I did not uninstall any of the previous Android stuff first.

Answer (score 52):

**NOTE: Use this approach with caution because this might break your Eclipse installation** *(see comments)*.

This might help you if you installed the ADT plugin **manually**. But if you are using the version of Eclipse from the [Eclipse ADT Bundle](https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html?pkg=adt) the below steps could break your Eclipse installation, and you may not be able to use Eclipse again!

Go to

Menu *Help* → *About Eclipse SDK* → <kbd>Installation Details</kbd>.

Now you will see all `22.0` versions and then click `Uninstall` button at bottom.

After uninstallation goto:

Menu *Help* → *Install New Software* → enter `http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/`

Then install all the things, and now it is ready.

Comment: This broke my eclipse installation.

Comment: Not working and my eclipse does not respond anymore.

Comment: This broke my eclipse too :/

Comment: I have done second step only and all is well again. Help --> Install New Software --> http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

Comment: I think this breaks eclipse in Mac OS.

Comment: It broke my eclipse installation :(

Comment: Somewhat worked for me.  Seems to be having problems with an app compatibility project (actionbar stuff?) maybe unrelated.

Comment: This should work "if you installed the ADT plugin manually...". Otherwise, does not. You can check this through Eclipse icon: " If you installed the ADT plugin manually you should have the standard purple eclipse icon. If you are using the ADT Bundle the launch icon will be green with curly braces." This works for me. 
Source: answer of Luke Deighton and others below on this post.

Comment: This broke my eclipse too on Mac OSX Mavericks. I think I will just re-install. The only conclusion i can draw from the 30+ answers is that there is no one good answer that works for everyone. Fastest seems to be just a re-install. Google terrible company what lousy support. Compared to Xcode Eclipse is just a mess quite frankly.

Comment: This broke my ADT v22.
Now I'm trying to install a new ADT bundle v22 instance and then i'll upgrade it with the offline package ADT-23.

Comment: Anyway... stop using ADT! Android Studio is the way!

Comment: This broke my eclipse :(

Answer (score 18):

I was updating my build server today and came across the same issue. It has been reported here:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=72419

The fix is in progress and the work around according to the project manager is:

> Please wait for an updated version within a day or two. Until then, your workaround is to do download one of
>
> http://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r22.6.2-linux.tgz
>
> http://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r22.6.2-windows.zip
>
> http://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r22.6.2-macosx.zip
>
> and copy over the following files:
>
> ```
>     tools/hprof-conv
>     tools/support/annotations.jar
>     tools/proguard
> ```

[edit]
zipalign was missing for me too, check to see if you need to copy this as well

Comment: Hi, these workaround does not work for me. Still get the same error

Comment: The author kept editing the question, this was in response to the question: where can the missing files be found.

Comment: I dont see the files that are supposed to be copied over in the download zip for Linux

Answer (score 17):

It works for me :)

If for some reason you installed an ADT preview and need to **revert back** to the current stable, you can't use the dialog to install "new" software since what you want is actually an older one. Instead do this:

- Open Help > About Eclipse... on Windows or Linux. On Mac, use the app's menu > About...
- Click the "Installation Details" button.
- Select the "Installation History" tab.
- Select one of the previous configurations.
- Click the "Revert" button at the bottom.

[image]

Answer (score 16):

is what they are saying about this:

**OK, guys, sorry about all this trouble, and we apologize for the messed up releases. Here's the summary:**

- There is no way to update an existing ADT bundle that you might have downloaded.
- You can do one of two options:

  1. Install Eclipse from eclipse.org and install ADT by pointing to the update site: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse
  2. Download bundles from here:

     - Linux 64-bit VM: http://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140702.zip
     - Linux 32-bit VM: http://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-linux-x86-20140702.zip
     - Mac: http://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702.zip
     - Windows 32-bit: http://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140702.zip
     - Windows 64-bit: http://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702.zip

Starting with ADT bundle 23.0.2, you should be able to update to future versions of ADT.

**Source:** https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=72912

Comment: It seems thats probably the most official source. I hope it will work in the future as they promise.

Answer (score 15):

I have done following to resolve an issue.

1. Go to http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html and download the latest ADT ZIP file (at the bottom of page).
2. Go to Eclipse → menu *Help* → *About Eclipse* → *Installation details*
3. Delete **Android DDM, Android Development Tools, Hierarchy Viewer, Native Development Tools, TraceView, etc., 22.X version**.
4. Menu Help* → *Install New Software* → *Add* → *Archive* → *Select the downloaded ZIP file in step 1.
5. Select all the latest version of all 23 which I have deleted in step 3 and accept the license agreement.

Restart Eclipse, and it fixes my issue.

Comment: I did the same (standalone Android SDK Manager) and got exactly to the point 'greywolf82' is complaining about. Your answer is not the solution.

Comment: Even I tried to uninstall Android Development Tool , but not able to start eclipse again . eclipse.exe file itself is gone after uninstalling Android Development tool for me.

Comment: DON'T DO THIS if you are using ADT bundle. ECLIPSE won't start after uninstalling ADT! This is only for people who added ADT to and existing eclipse installation.

Answer (score 9):

Only helped:

1. Fresh Eclipse installation (http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-developers/lunar)
2. Help --> Install New Software --> https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

Comment: Yep. But rev 23 is BROKEN. proguard is missing, annotation.jar is missing and other tools. See the bug report linked above, Google replied to us telling that it should be fixed within a few days, now we can use as workaround the link posted in their reply to copy by hand the missing part.

Comment: For Mac this advice was usefull.

Answer (score 8):

If you install a new [Eclipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29) version it will work.
Here's what I did:

1. Installed the new Eclipse version, Luna
2. Made a backup of the current workspace.
3. Ran the new Eclipse, Luna, and updated the workspace
4. Installed the [ADT plugin](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html) (Help -> Install New Software)
5. Restarted Eclipse
6. Done

Comment: But be warned, GPE (google plug-in for eclipse) doesn't support Luna yet.  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-plugin-eclipse/4YACQROrB2U

Answer (score 8):

There is a lot of confusion going around in this thread. There are two solutions depending on how you installed ADT.

1. If you installed the ADT plugin manually then I believe you can use the "Delete ADT" -> "Install New Software" approach.
2. If you are using the ADT Bundle then do not follow that solution! You will break Eclipse. Here is an update from a Google member - read #18:

   https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=72912

You must download a new version of the ADT-Bundle (yep, it's frustrating!).

Comment: Don't remember which approach I took - is there some way to tell?

Comment: @Tom If you used option 1 you should have the standard purple eclipse icon. If you used option 2 the launch icon will be green with curly braces.

Comment: Thank you for posting the location where ADT can be uninstalled, that was what I didn`t find :)

Answer (score 7):

- Just uninstall the previous ADT.
- Go to menu *Help* → *About Eclipse* → <kbd>Installation Details</kbd>
- Uninstall all plugins which Id start with com.android.ide
- Install ADT again from the update site.

Comment: will it broke my Eclipse?

Comment: @Sharmilee: once you install new ADT, you will be able to work again.

Comment: This works perfectly...when you DON'T restart Eclipse after the existing plugins are uninstalled. Eclipse would ask to restart, DON'T restart it at that point but continue adding the new version from "Install new software". Once the new plugins are added, restart Eclipse and it's all set.

Comment: After I reinstall ADT I get this error: [2015-09-19 21:54:06 - Android SDK] Error when loading the SDK: Error: Error parsing /Applications/android-sdk-macosx/system-images/android-22/android-wear/armeabi-v7a/devices.xml
cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid content was found starting with element 'd:skin'.

Comment: After I reinstall ADT I got new errors but I updated the Android thingy using the Android iCon in Eclipse, and now it works!! WOW thank you so much. THIS ANSWER IS THE ONLY WORKING ANSWER IN THIS QUESTION!!! TRY THIS

Answer (score 6):

**DO NOT DO THIS**

**Warning: Please see the comments below this answer. These steps have had a negative impact for many people.**

1. Click Help / Install new software...
2. Click on What is "already installed" (as in picture below)
3. In the new window you can uninstall the old ADT (uninstall Android Development Tools, Android DDMS, Android Hierarchy Viewer, Android TraceView, Android Native Development Tools and Tracer for OpenGL ES)
4. Restart Eclipse
5. Then again click on Help / Install New Software
6. Choose ADT... Install

I hope it helps!

[image: Picture Demonstration]

Comment: It is impossible to remove "Android Development Tools". `An error occurred while uninstalling
session context was:(profile=profile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Uninstall, operand=[R]org.eclipse.rcp.configuration_root.win32.win32.x86_64 1.0.0.M20130204-1200 --> null, action=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.touchpoint.natives.actions.CleanupzipAction).
Backup of file D:\dev\android\eclipse\eclipse.exe failed.
Can not remove : D:\dev\android\eclipse\eclipse.exe`

Comment: Hmmm.. I just did it few minutes ago. 
Have you tried running Eclipse as Administrator?

Comment: Same error in Administrator mode. Might be that my version is just too old, I'm using Eclipse from 20131030 ADT Bundle.

Comment: I followed these steps, but I am unable to restart eclipse. I am getting the following error: The Eclipse executable launcher was unable to locate its companion shared library. The following error log was generated: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=BUsMX75L

Comment: Eclipse won't start for me after uninstalling these things. I get an error log file with the following...  The bundle "org.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins_1.1.200.v20120301-2145 [142]" could not be resolved.

Comment: Why do we need to uninstall the previous version manually? I tried that 15 min ago and I could not restart Eclipse because some libraries could not be found. These issues should be handled internally by Eclipse, this is a massive waste of time

Comment: @Biljana how did you manage to uninstall that list of items? My Eclipse won't let me uninstall single items, it only gives the option to uninstall the whole ADT

Comment: THIS BREAKS THE ADT COMPLETELY..it won't start anymore. Thanks.

Comment: These deletes the whole Eclipse executable. Doesn't work

Comment: This deleted eclipse executable file.

Comment: @SheikhAman: Can you tell how to recover the deleted eclipse executable file ?

Comment: I don't think you can recover it. At extremes you can try using a tool like `photorec` but that would be an overkill. Why don't you reinstall Eclipse?

Comment: Confirmed: Eclipse will not start for me now.  :|

Comment: @AlécioCarvalho and everyone else who broke your executable: You're supposed to remove development tools, not developer tools. Next time read the instructions closer.

Comment: Nope, I can uninstall everything except android developer tools, and with it I cannot install the new ones (and it still says that I have  Hierarchy Viewer, Traceview installed...) regardless of that I have uninstalled them previously...

Comment: Everyone should downvote this since it breaks the whole thing!

Comment: It also broke my ADT install. I just added a warning to read the comments before following the answer.

Comment: This worked fine for me, only needed one file to be copied over from a previous build as shown by w1 below

Comment: It broke the ADT completely. Then I realisd that I could not even revert back to the v22 coz it had been uninstalled already! At the end I had to download the plugin from Google and install as local archive in Eclipse. This eventually worked for me. http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html#Download

Comment: My Eclipse wont even start now

Comment: crap, well about to find out if this f-ed up my eclipse installation. I guess in all fairness it wasn't working before :-/

Comment: yep, it deletes eclipse

Answer (score 5):

After trying the approaches in other answers without success, I just installed a new bundle from http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html?pkg=adt and that worked fine.

Do the following:

1. As you don't want to re-download all the platforms again, copy the existing one from */OLD_ANDROID_SDK_PATH/sdk/platforms* to */NEW_ANDROID_SDK_PATH/sdk/platforms*.
2. When opening the new Eclipse from the recent downloaded bundle, make sure you reuse the previous 'workspace' folder. That will ensure that all your previous settings will be remembered.
3. After opening the new Eclipse on the previous workspace, please check if the used Android SDK is pointing to the new one (Eclipse preferences -> Android). It might be pointing to the old one, as you've reused the previews workspace settings.

With these steps, you should't have to reconfigure everything, and you won't need to spend time troubleshooting this **BUG** on this upgrade from Google Developers.

Good luck! ;-)

Answer (score 5):

You need to uninstall the old version and install 23

uninstall:
Help > about Eclipse SDK > Installation Details 
select Android related packages to uninstall

And then install V23.

Comment: By far the simplest solution! Please note that the "About Eclipse" menu item might be found under "Eclipse" rather than under "Help" in some cases.

Comment: The easier, logical and simplest solution !

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to update an existing ADT bundle that you might have downloaded.

You can do one of two options:

1. Install Eclipse from eclipse.org and install ADT by pointing to the update site: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse
2. Download bundles from:

   - Linux 64 bit VM: http://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140702.zip
   - Linux 32 bit VM: http://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-linux-x86-20140702.zip
   - Mac: http://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702.zip
   - Windows 32 bit: http://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140702.zip
   - Windows 64 bit: http://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702.zip

Starting with ADT bundle 23.0.2, you should be able to update to future versions of ADT.

Comment: New Eclipse SDK bundle works. Looks like there are some icons missing from toolbar, but besides that I can finally compile my application.

Comment: I guess they are making us migrate to Android Studio! But I hope all essential icons are available in toolbar! :)

Answer (score 3):

I was getting the same "conflicting dependency" error on Mac OS X 10.9.3 and simply upgrading was not an option.  What finally worked was downloading the latest ***Eclipse ADT bundle*** zip file from developer.android.com, extracting it and moving only "eclipse" folder to the place where my old eclipse folder was. (extracting the Eclipse ADT bundle zip file will give you "eclipse" and "sdk" folders).

If you decide to go the same route, first make sure you know what your Workspace path is. This can be found in Preferences.  Then rename your old "eclipse" directory (not Eclipse.app) to something like eclipse-22.6.3, then move extracted "eclipse" folder into its place. Run new Eclipse.app inside, and when it asks you about Workspace, just enter the same path as you noted above.  Or it can also be set later in Preferences.

Maybe worth adding is that to re-enable **Android SDK Manager** and **Android Virtual Device Manager** choose *Window -> Customize Perspective -> Command Groups Availability* and select **Android SDK and AVD Manager**. This will add these 2 items to the "Window" menu item for the current perspective (Java).

I didn't move the extracted "sdk" folder, because I already had sdk folder in the same directory as eclipse, which I have already updated to the latest Android tools. But if it makes you feel safer, you can also rename your old sdk folder (for backup purposes) and move the freshly extracted one into its place.

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same problem and solved it. You need to uninstall the Android plugin entirely from within Eclipse (from the "about" section..), including trace view..

Then added the ADT Plugin again (https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/) and install it.

The problem is solved!

I guess it's a bug with the SDK manager or ADT Plugin update mechanism...

Answer (score 3):

How to update from 22.xx.x to 23.0.2 (my solution).  This will beat the dependency issues.

I was suffering from this issue for days, and I have tried every single solution on this link, but no luck. I finally figured out a solution that actually works!

Please note that this solution works in Windows 7 (64 bit). It should probably work for other Windows operating systems.

Here we go:

1. download the latest ADT bundle from

   http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#download
2. unzip it and open "eclipse" folder --> "plugins" folder
3. Now go to your old eclipse and open "eclipse" folder --> "plugins" folder, and copy everything inside.
4. Now paste them into the "plugins" folder of the (NEW ECLIPSE), but DO NOT overwrite anything.
5. While inside of the "plugins" folder of your new Eclipse, do the search. Type in `22.` (notice 22 with a dot) and hit enter.
6. The search result will show up all the files or folders with .....22.6...... For example,

   ```
   com.android.ide.eclipse.adt_**22.6.2**.v201403212031-1085508
   ```
7. Highlight all of these files/folders and hit delete key.
8. Make sure to update your old API/SDK to the latest version and load this sdk directory to work with your new eclipse.

**or**

You can watch this video, which shows you how to move all your SDK/API to your new SDK folder.

Link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jPZpJdnbbN0

I have not tried to update from any other ADT versions, but I think it should work for any old ADT versions too.

**Don't forget to backup stuff before attempting.**

Answer (score 2):

On ADT-bundled Eclipse I had to first uninstall the ADT and then do a fresh install.

To remove the ADT plugin from Eclipse:

- Go to menu *Help* → *About Eclipse* → *Installation Details*.
- Select ADT plug-in, then click Uninstall.
- After uninstallation install ADT from Help → Install new software.

Comment: I installed the new version from web site but it seems that with SDK tools rev 23 under sdk dir/tools there is no more the proguard folder! Can you share it?

Answer (score 2):

What I have just found is that you need to update your ADT plugin in your Eclipse (whether stand alone or ADT Bundle) before updating your build tool.

If your Eclipse installation points to the most recent Build Tool and your Eclipse is having ADT 22.x, it will show those errors.

**What worked for me: (on Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit)**

- Installed an older version of Eclipse and ADT (from the Bundle)
- This copy of Eclipse was pointing to an older SDK verion with old build tools (before 20)
- Updated the ADT to v23 (via archive, in my case)
- Pointed Eclipse to the latest version of build tools.

You may not have an older copy of Eclipse and Build tools, in that case you can uninstall latest build tool from SDK Manager and install the older copy.
Once everything starts working fine, do the above steps.

I am trying to upload older copies of such bundles somewhere on the Internet, will update the links here, once I am done uploading.

Answer (score 2):

I found these instructions in a comment.

Download the newest version of ADT and use your existing workspace.  This is actually the least pain-full upgrade you'll ever do.  It didn't mess with the .android folder so I still had my original debug key.  Only things missing were a couple of add ons I hardly ever use and they are easily installed into the new version.

Note don't install into your existing adt folder create a new folder so you can still fall back if the new install doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

For me it helped to delete Android 4.4W which is also API 20 and might be a cause for the conflict. So only install Android 4.4W or Android L until they fix it.

And (again this might only be for me) it only works in Android Studio not in Eclipse ...

Comment: Yep. I installed only Android L but it doesn't work. I'm installing Eclipse again downloading the last ADT bundle from Android web site.

Comment: Don't wanna rollback to Eclipse Juno but seems like the only way :( Android L Emu is being stuck within Eclipse 4.4 and Android Studio

Comment: I installed Juno but now it seems the proguard folder is not under sdkdir/tools :(

Comment: Make sure you grab the complete bundle from android developer site. That worked for me

Comment: Yes I downloaded the complete bundle not SDK only. Have you got proguard now?

Answer (score 1):

I had to delete ADT and install it again.

**However be warned**, this caused me and one other person to have an annotations.jar missing errors in the Java Build path for certain projects, probably because it was trying to look for an old SDK, so upgrading projects is the next step I have to take.

The errors relate to libraries mostly, Google Play Services, Facebook SDK, ActionBarCompat.

For this step, you uninstall ADT, then put the URL back in to download them. The url is: `https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse`

Comment: I do not. Is this another effect you think?

Comment: Oh my god. Google what you have done!?!?!? Yes. The SDK rev 23 is buggy :(

Comment: Related question for missing annotations.jar: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24438748/1402846

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution for the problem with "conflicting dependency". I don't have the same page of Daniel Díaz's response, but a page show "conflicting dependency", and I can't make anything.

The problem is that I'm not the owner of the file. Eclipse was installed in other session (on OS X). I have the right to read and write the Eclipse file, but I'm not the owner. Make a "chown" command on all Eclipse files to solve the problem. After, I have the same result as Daniel Diaz.

I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

If Eclipse gives an error after uninstalling the ADT plugin from your Eclipse installation, try to edit file `config.ini` in the Eclipse folder → configuration. Find:

```
eclipse.application=
```

And change it to:

```
eclipse.application=org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench
```

I hope it works for you too.

Answer (score 1):

WARNING

There is now an update for ADT 23.0.1, but the Windows and Linux scripts are messed up, so wait with the upgrade!

You could check for example tools/proguard/bin/*.sh in http://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r23.0.1-windows.zip.

Answer (score 1):

I simply went to my Android resources folder on my C:/ drive (`C:/Android`), deleted the 'eclipse' folder and all its contents. I downloaded Android Developer Tools once more and just moved over the 'eclipse' folder.

I started up and everything was fine; I had updated to version 23.

Hopefully this helps, possibly not suitable for everyone as some of you have Eclipse modifications but for someone who, like me, wanted a quick fix and get back to developing this seemed to be the easiest path.

Answer (score 1):

I am using [Eclipse v4.3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29#Releases) (Kepler), and this is how I solved my problem.

Goto menu *Help* → *Install new software* → click *Add*.

In the popup, give any name (I named it as Eclipse ADT Plugin), and in the link's place, use https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

Once you click OK, you will be displayed with new packages that will be installed and old packages that will be deleted. Don't worry about these packages. Click <kbd>OK</kbd>.

New packages will be installed, and this should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Solution, see: *http://bazalabs.com/solution-for-the-update-problem-of-android-developer-toolkit-version-23-0-0-or-above/*

This solution is the correct way of how you should change the files and keep your Eclipse ADT and not downloading a new one.

Comment: The link seem to be (effectively) broken (redirects to `http://ww12.bazalabs.com/`). Can you confirm?

Answer (score 1):

I did this to solve the same issue (in OS X):

1. Help > Install New Software > Add or select this repository "http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.3"
2. Under "Eclipse platform" select the newest version of Eclipse.
3. The installer will ask if you want to uninstall the ADT, click finish.
4. Restart Eclipse and install ONLY the ADT 23 using this repository: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse.
5. Restart Eclipse and install DDMS, Hierarchy Viewer, Trace View etc.
6. Restart Eclipse again.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

After hours of struggling with this issue I finally decided to get rid of the update. I'm posting this just in case you want to go back to version 22.6.2:

1. Open the SDK Manager
2. Leave everything unchecked but the first option (the one with ADT version 23)
3. Delete that package
4. Restart Eclipse

Hope this helps

Comment: @LukeDeighton what happened? I'm sorry this caused problems, I just posted what worked for me.

Comment: @alvaro.delasema This doesn't work for anyone using the ADT-Bundle from the Android developer site (I think). Eclipse fails to open once ADT is uninstalled

Answer (score 0):

Download the ADT v23 plugin from Google and install it as local archive from the downloaded zip file in Eclipse.

http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html#Download

Comment: You cannot do this, because of a conflicting dependency as explained in original question, almost in linux. Removing old ADT plugin by hand is not recommended, as explained here. If you search for ADT plugin updated, eclipse says that there is none, so you can not update adt normal way. Google's ADT plugin update is broken!

For me what worked is install ADT bundle in new place and reinstall all tools again. This method needs some work, but it worked for me. I explained it in my answer, how to do it carefully, saving your devoloping keys, settings and projects.

Answer (score 0):

I have followed instructions found here and tried to fix my old Eclipse + SDK + ADT, but with no luck. The basic problem keeps beeing the same; I still get the error message:

> This Android SDK requires Android Developer Toolkit version 23.0.0 or above. Current version is 22.6.3.v201404151837-1123206. Please update ADT to the latest version.

But my eclipse can't find updates and can't install ADT 23 as new software. So I can't compile my old project in my workspace.

I tested a fresh eclipode bundle for Windows 8, followed instructions found from Android's developers page, step by step, and it worked fine. So it seems that the Windows Eclipse build is not broken. But I wan't use my Linux installation, my old Ubuntu 10. It seems obvious, that to getting the Linux Eclipse environment working again, I must install a new Eclipse bundle, my old Eclipse won't ever see updates for ADT 23 to get things working. Again, these intructions are for Linux developers that wan't to get their old workspace projects working again without changes in the developing environment, except you must install a new Eclipse bundle, but after that your projects will work as well as before the version 23 SDK/ADT-mess.

1. If you are an Android developer you want to be sure, that you developing environment won't be messed up. Backup:

   - ~./android (Here are your developer keys)
   - Your old SDK dirrectory
   - Your workspace
2. Download the Eclipse bundle, [Get the Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html).
3. Follow instructions, create directory `~/Development` and unzip bundle there. You get Eclipse and SDK directories.
4. Start Eclipse from that directory
5. Eclipse asks for a workspace. You can give it the old one.
6. In Eclipse settings set SDK as downloaded SDK.
7. Start Android SDK manager and download tools, Android versions you use and extras said in the Android developer tool page instructions
8. You should now be ready to compile your old projects again, but for me it was not that simple. My old projects had errors. So open problems windows and you get to know that annotation.jar is missing. So you must copy `annotations.jar` from your old SDK, from, the backup you made, or from the older `sdk.zip` explained in this thread to <new SDK>/tools/support/annotations.jar

After that I could use my old workspace in Ubuntu and compile and launch applications to Android devices. It was that simple. Thanks Google ;-(

Answer (score 0):

There are many possible answers to this question. I think it all depends on what your environment and installation procedure is. I'm running into the same issue as stated multiple times above. I cannot install ADT 23 because of a conflict dependency.

This is my environment:

I'm running Windows 7 64-bit with Eclipse 4.2.2. I installed ADT through menu *Help* → *Install New Software*.

My solution:

Menu *Help* → *About Eclipse* → *Uninstall* → ALL_ANDROID. Then I simply installed each of the ADT 23 tools through the "Install New Software".

Note: This is with the LATEST ADT release.

Answer (score 0):

It's working to uninstall the old files, but you don't have to restart Eclipse. After the uninstall process, install the new software and then restart Eclipse.

It was quite simple and works for me.

Answer (score 0):

- I solved these problem by deleting the ADT Bundle which was showing
  an error.
- Then I *extracted* the new ADT bundle to solve these problems. After that, I just updated the Android 4.4.2(API 19) in Android SDK Manager.
- You are getting these errors because of updating the Android SDK
  Tools 22.6.2. Below I show the screenshot of it.

  [image]
- Install everything as shown in the screenshot itself. Then these
  problems will not occur again.

Answer (score 0):

The answers already provided display how much the solution depends on your particular environment. I initially tried upgrading a Windows 8.1 machine; when that failed I tried upgrading a Vista PC. When that failed, I tried Android Studio on the Win 8.1. The problems that we all are encountering are resulting in different solutions because of version conflicts between O/S, Eclipse, Java and, of course, the Google debacle.

Here's what I did:
I gave up on the bundle. For Vista I installed Eclipse 4.3.2 (Kepler) and downloaded the SDK installer which loaded 23.0.2. Already had jdk1.6 installed. Only gotcha left was to use the SDK manager to download my minimum platform (API 8) - V20 isn't that far backward compatible. But at least now I am not totally dead in the water.

For Windows 8.1 Android Studio seemed to install. But when I tried to install my Project, it stopped when it complained that google-play-services_lib was not included. I had not been using it, so it appears this is a requirement of Android Studio. Really?

So I went back to Eclipse. I had installed Luna and jdk8u5 but then tried to revert to what worked for Vista. jdk1.6 is not available from Oracle so I had to download 1.7 and hope. Downloaded the SDK which again got 23.0.2. So far so good.

Problem then was installer-r23.0.2-windows apparently is hardwired to find JDK at 'C:\Windows\system32\java.exe':[2]. I set the PATH to jdk1.7.0_65\bin and set JAVA_HOME environment variable to it also. Neither worked. Installer still choked on java8 in Windows\System32.

So I renamed C:\Windows\System32\java.exe to disable it and the installer-r23 found C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\bin\java.exe. The installer completed successfully. Why it didn't like the same file (V8.0.5.13) in Windows\System 32 is a mystery to me but maybe a clue to someone.

Still had to download API 8, but I thought I was operational on the 8.1 machine too.

Except for getting Eclipse to recognize my Motorola RazrM as a USB-attached device. That required going to the Win8.1 DeviceManager and updating the Mot Composite ADB Interface in ADB Interface. That required a download of the Motorola Device Manager. Still the phone did not appear in the Eclipse Devices View. It was waiting for a new confirmation on the phone that apparently has been added to the latest ADT. While I needed to upgrade the driver on my Samsung 10.1 tablet, it had not added the connection request confirmation.

Finally, the nightmares were over. My biggest problem appears to have been leaping to the latest versions - and then trying to regress when 23.0 broke. I think I learned a hard lesson. But, really, does it have to be this hard???

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Complete procedure to **download ADT, configure it in Eclipse, and fixing dependency issues**:

**Download ADT:**

1. Open this link: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/
2. Download ADT-23.0.2.zip which is the latest version to a ZIP folder and don't unzip it.

**Configure ADT in Eclipse:**

1. Open Eclipse → go to menu *Help* → *Install New Software...*
2. Click on <kbd>Add..</kbd> button on the right.
3. The *Add Repository* dialog will open.
4. In *Name*: write *ADT Plugin*
5. In *Location*: enter path of the ADT zipped folder which you have downloaded by clicking on **Archive..** button.

**An error may come as duplicate location. To solve it, follow the below steps:

1.1 Close the current dialog box.

1.2 Click on **Available software sites** link, and select the entry which has the same location as you have added the zipped file or ADT Plugin entry. After selecting, remove it.

1.3 Then again, come to the previous <kbd>Add...</kbd> dialog.

1.4 Again, add *Name* and *Location* in the *Add Repository* dialog box.

**Select all the options in *Development Tools* and click on <kbd>Next</kbd> to install the ADT completely.**

**Fixing dependency issues in ADT:** After all the above steps, dependency issues may come. To solve it, follow the following steps:

1. Click on **Already installed** in the *Install* dialog box.
2. Click on *Installed Software* tab, and now select all the development tools of the previous version looking at versions and uninstall them.

Now all the issues of dependency issues would evaporate and follow the Next, Next wizard to install:)

**All the best. It will definitely help.**

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. I kept upgrading to version 23.02 (or 23.03 if presented) using a new install of ADT bundle, and migrating the your original workspace across and add the patches. **This is the procedure for ADT Bundle only.**

(Backup your workspace first)

1/ install latest adt bundle from google. (For some reason using Googles download page just goes around in a loop on Chrome!?!)

- linux 64 bit vm:http://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140702.zip
- linux 32 bit vm:http://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-linux-x86-20140702.zip
- mac:http://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702.zip
- win32:http://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140702.zip
- win64:http://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702.zip

2/ download the patch from here:

- linux http://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r22.6.2-linux.tgz
- Windoze http://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r22.6.2-windows.zip
- Mac http://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r22.6.2-macosx.zip

3/ Apply the patch as per [Googles (poorly described) instructions](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=72419#c12)

*...and copy over the following files:*

tools/hprof-conv
tools/support/annotations.jar
tools/proguard

Which means => Copy the file only of tools/hprof-conv
Which means => Copy the file only of tools/support/annotations.jar
Which means => Copy the directory and all contents for tools/proguard

3/ Point your old workspace to the new install on startup.
(Projects will still come up with errors, don't worry)

4/ select Help-> Install new software, select update site, and select version 23.03 when prompted.

- Check the update sites, and edit the one for google from https => http like this:
  [image: Change to "http"]. This seems to make Eclipse Updater build a new update profile that avoided download errors. You might also get "unsigned" prompt warning prompts from Windoze but just "Allow Access" to prevent blocking.

5/ If you still get errors on references to "android.R", this is because you may not have the appropriate "platform build tools". Check the "Android SDK Manager" for which build tools you have like this:
[image]
Also check your "Android" build for the project to make sure you have the compatible Android API.

Version 23.02 should be downloaded, and your projects should now compile.

Google have abandoned all the UI trimmings for Eclipse ADT (ie you'll see the Juno splash). I thought this would be a problem but it seems ok. I think it shows how desperate Google were to get the fix out. Given that Android studio is not far away Google don't want invest any more time into ADT. I suppose this is what you get with "free" software. Hopefully the adults are back in charge now, and Google Studio won't be such a disaster.

Answer (score 0):

Based on win7.
Eclipse 
Version: 4.2.2
Build id: M20130204-1200

For those who broke Eclipse after trying to uninstall ADT plugin.

You need to remove all *android* folder/jars from plugin folder and features folder.

Then check your config.ini in /configuration. Probably you have these lines:

```
eclipse.product=
```

...

```
eclipse.application=
```

change them like this:

```
eclipse.product=org.eclipse.platform.ide
eclipse.application=org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench
```

Maybe needed to run your eclipse from command line:

```
eclipsec.exe -clean.
```

Then I could install the newest ADT plugin, without needing to download whole eclipse packages and loosing all configuration/plugins.

Answer (score 0):

The prefect answers is. Enter the follow path,copy all of them
`Macintosh HD ▸ 应用程序 ▸ adt-bundle-mac ▸ sdk ▸ platform-tools`
then parse into  `Macintosh HD ▸ 应用程序 ▸ adt-bundle-mac ▸ sdk ▸ tools`,
last,edit the line `plugin.version=23.0.0` of file `Macintosh HD ▸ 应用程序 ▸ adt-bundle-mac ▸ sdk ▸ tools ▸plugin.prop` ,such as `plugin.version=21.0.0`.
  restart eclipse.everything is all-right.

Comment: For me the problem was caused by trying to upgrade to 23 from 22 since Eclipse said I had to. But it only allowed me to install one of the 23 components. All the rest stayed at 22. Of course, nothing worked. So following this advice I uninstalled all the 22s and the 1 23 and reinstalled just the 23. At least I see the SDK versions load.

Answer (score -1):

There is a new update available.

- Update your Android SDK Tool to 23.0.1
- Update your Eclipse. Go to *Help* -> *Check for update*
- Then restart your Eclipse

This will fix the empty src & layout issue.

[image]

Comment: This does not fix the problem for me with Windows/Eclipse.

Comment: That's the problem - on Windows you can't update the ADT plug-in.  It still says "cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency".

Comment: Check out Daniel Díaz answer,you need to completely uninstall the previous update and install the fresh one.
Check out this [link](http://i.stack.imgur.com/CYZHN.png)