# Can't see android L in SDK

Tags: android, sdk, android-5.0-lollipop

I just figured out that Google has released [Android L SDK platform](http://developer.android.com/preview/setup-sdk.html)

In that page it says that :

```
Start the Android SDK Manager.

In the Tools section, select the latest Android SDK Tools, Platform-tools, and Build-tools.

Select everything under the Android L Developer Preview section and click Install packages...
```

But when I start the SDK I can't see any sign of android L. Here is a screenshot:

[image: the screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after couple of hours i saw an update for sdk tools and i have updated that to version 23 and then android L appeared ):

Answer (score 3):

Restart the SDK Manager after having installed the latest SDK Tools and SDK Platform-tools, and the L items should appear. Leastways, that's what I had to do.

Comment: i have installed the latest version of everything and restarted several times with no luck !

Comment: @Mahfa: Based on your screenshot, you don't have the latest SDK Build-tools installed -- try installing that, then restarting the SDK Manager.

Comment: ops sorry i am installing!

Comment: @CommonsWare, the build tools is not necessary to get the L images.
Mahfa, try to empty the repo cache (C:\Users\{username]\.android\cache), and restarting the SDK Manager. Let it update!

Comment: @CommonsWare i restated the sdk after updating Build-tools but no luck again ):

Comment: @Mahfa did you remove ALL the files, including the hidden ones? If you haven't made any significant changes to the SDK configuration or have any important emulators in C:\Users\[username]\.android, I'd suggest deleting the whole folder.

Comment: @fonix232 i deleted the whole folder and restarted the sdk but no luck again ! ):

Comment: @Rashid: I have installed latest SDk tools and platform-tools and I can see Android L sdk in my SDK manager but my eclipse shows error to update ADT plugin like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24437564/update-eclipse-with-android-development-tools-23

Comment: @r.bhardwaj have u already updated the ADT plugins?? i am using the latest version of adt bundle from google..

Comment: @Rashid: I have tried "Check for updates" and also tried installing ADT plugin using "Installing new software" but nothing works :(

Answer (score 1):

You need to download latest android SDK Tools (i.e Rev. 23 ) & platform - tools (Rev. 20).
After Installing these latest sdk tools & platform-tools again open the sdk manager and bingo..! You will find out the L Developer Preview. Enjoy..!