# How to install android Lollipop in eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-sdk-tools, android-5.0-lollipop

This android [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/preview/setup-sdk.html) says that installation procedure of android Lollipop.

in third step they says that

> Select everything under the Android L Developer Preview section and click Install packages.

But I unable to find any section like `android L developer preview`. Where to download it I follow all the steps from my eclipse juno.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

### Note:

Before installing latest tools in SDK manager, I would recommend you to update ADT plugin from Help -> Check for updates. Otherwise you would have to face issue described here: [Update Eclipse with Android development tools v. 23](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24437564/update-eclipse-with-android-development-tools-23)

### Answer:

As mentioned in 2<sup>nd</sup> step, first you have to install latest **SDK Tools**, **Platform-tools**, and **Build-tools**.

[image]

### Next Step:

After installing latest tools, you will get **Android L** and **Android 4.4W** sections:

[image]

Comment: Initially I check for Updates. But It says there is no updates. Right now SDK require  to update of Eclipse . same check for update option have no updates.

Comment: Now it Sucks. I did Certain steps and adt gone need to download eclipse again i think.

Comment: @ShabbirDhangot: Yeah dude it happened with me too. I had downloaded these things several times, at the end that weird ADT problem comes and when I check for updates, "No Updates Found".

Comment: @SpringBreaker Agree. It was happened twice for my personal laptops.

Answer (score 2):

Update all the SDK tools and restart the SDK manager for the Android L sections to show up.

Answer (score 1):

Since now the Android lollipop came try to install and explore from u can download from android site. Api 21
 Here u can find guide also for setup:
http://androidgreeve.blogspot.in/2014/10/step-by-step-guide-to-install-and.html?m=1