# Android Lollipop is not listed in Eclipse Target SDK even after installing latest SDK

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am trying to update my Eclipse to Android Lollipop. I am done with downloading the required SDK  and installing the same. My problem is that after doing this when I try to create a new project for Android 5.0 it does not list it in the Target SDk drop down. However, When I go to the android folder where I have downloaded the latest SDK and run it it does enlist Android 5.0 there but does not show it when I run SDK Manager from eclipse. I have done lot of troubleshooting like re-installing the whole eclipse again and followed steps given in various same kind of questions but nothing seems working for me.

Comment: restart ur eclipse ?

Comment: I can confirm that this is an issue for me as well. I can't create a new project that uses 5.0 as the target. The latest one I see is `API 21: 4.X (L Preview)`. It's easy to work around this, however, because after you create the project you can then set the target to 5.0.

Comment: I have done restarting the eclipse no of times and even restarted my computer but did not help and ADT version is not updating as well

Comment: how can i set the target to 5.0 when the peoject has been created

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24445151/how-to-install-android-lolipop-in-eclipse

Answer (score 0):

You have to right click on your project in Eclipse --> Properties --> Android --> Project Build Target and then select Android 5.0.1.

Also you may need to check AndroidManifest.xml for the targetSdkVersion value and target attribute in your project.properties file.

Clean and build your project and you will be fine.

Comment: Thanks a ton for answering...however this is the issue it does not list Android 5.0.1 under Project Build Target..After re-installing every thing and re-downloading ADT 23.0.4 when i set the SDK path it gives an error "This Android SDK requires Android Developer Toolkit version 23.0.0 or above.  Current version is 22.3.0.v201310242005-887826"

Comment: It seems that there is a problem with proguard missing file. Please check [this](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=72419) out. Also have a look a [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24437564/update-eclipse-with-android-development-tools-v-23?rq=1) thread from SO.

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24445151/how-to-install-android-lolipop-in-eclipse