# Error in updating to ADT rev 23 for Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, adt, eclipse-adt

- Recently I updated Android SDK tools to rev 23.0 from the Android SDK Manager. After restarting the eclipse IDE I'm getting an error message saying "`The Android SDK requires Android Developer Toolkit version 23.0.0 or above`"(Attached the picture of error dialog in the end).

  To solve this error I updated my ADT by following the below steps

  **Menu-->Help-->Install New Software-->Add-->Added ADT update site**  and updated the ADT to rev 23.0.0.1245622.
- After updating I restarted my eclipse and my eclipse started to display the old error message which I got in the above step `The Android SDK requires Android Developer Toolkit version 23.0.0.x or above`.

  I checked the version of my ADT plugin in Help-->About menu, it also shows the version as 22.0.0 and also my SDK says in my Android preferences in eclipse it shows the following error

  `This Android SDK requires Android Developer Toolkit version 23.0.0.x or above.  Current version is 22.0.5.v201307292155--757759.  Please update ADT to the latest version` .
  [image: Error Message in Android Preference Dialog]**Error Message in Android Preference Dialog**
- At this point I tried to update the ADT to rev 23.0.0. again using the **Menu-->Help-->Install New Software** which shows me the following screen

  [image: This image shows that ADT is already updated to 23.0.0.x]**This image shows that ADT is already updated to 23.0.0.x**
- Finally,I again restarted the eclipse which shows the following initialization dialog

  [image: This image shows ADT version as 22.0.0]

  **This shows ADT version as 22.0.0**
- After work bench is loaded I get following error Dialog which I got in my previous attempts mentioned above

  [image: ADT Version Error Message]
  **ADT Version Error Message.**

Can Someone please guide me to solve this issue of weird behavior of my eclipse and ADT plugin.

Comment: Having the same issue...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24437564/update-eclipse-with-android-development-tools-23

Comment: I tried changing the workspace and the error is gone for now, presently I'm not going to install the new update, the error will popup as soon as you install Android W or L from SDK Manager.

Comment: prince : some solutions were provided on Vyshakh Amarnath's link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24437564/update-eclipse-with-android-development-tools-23

Comment: None of them worked for me