# ADT wont update to 23 because of dependency conflict

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I am just starting android dev and was launching adt for the first time after installing all the past APIs from the sdk manager (down to 2.2 froyo) and i get an error telling me to update, but when it checks for an update it says no new updates.

moreover when i try to manually install the new adt from https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ i get a dependency conflict error.

Also when i download a fresh adt from google it seems to just be regular Juno eclipse with no adroid stuff set up, with no adt splash screen or anything...

I can't proceed to learn android if i cant use the IDE because it needs to update to an adt version that it wont install.

I have tried manually downloading the adt v23 and the same error occurs, i even deleted all the adt 22 related stuff in the plugins of the eclipse directory and it somehow STILL occurs

Comment: I ended up downloading a fresh ADT Bundle. Juno splash is there but it works just fine.

Comment: Is there a way to replace the adt without having to redownload all the SDKs again from the sdk manager? or should i just redownload them all?

Comment: In theory... It should work when you remove the old one and install the new one. But I couldn't manage to get it to work. Here is the relevant question http://stackoverflow.com/a/24438977/655987

Comment: what is going on with googles new release of the adt? why is the adt splash gone?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Update eclipse with Android Development tools 23](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24437564/update-eclipse-with-android-development-tools-23)

Answer (score 3):

Came across the same issue. Hence, I Deleted the old Eclipse cum Android SDK bundle and installed new bundle (Eclipse JUNO & Android) click [here](https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#download) to download. Working fine now. As your workspace is in a different directory, noting happens to your project.

Answer (score 2):

Just delete old eclipse folder and re-install new bundle from the official website. http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html works for me!