# Src folder is empty after updating to latest Android SDK 23,when i create a new black Activity for Android project

Tags: android, adt, eclipse-adt

I have updated my ADT plugin to 23,even Android SDK Tool to 23 & Platform-tool to 20.

why i'm getting Src & Layout folder as empty . And i have already fixed this issue "[Update eclipse with Android Development tools 23](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24437564/update-eclipse-with-android-development-tools-23)".

[image]

When i create a new project,my src folder will be empty.
I tried by updating eclipse , every thing is uptodate.
How can i fix this ?

[image]

But when i create a blank Ware activity for android watch,now src folder is not empty but it troughs me this error.

```
WatchActivity cannot be resolved to a type
```

[image]

Comment: @ChrisF my question over here is, why i'm getting the empty folder after the creation of a new project not about the Error you mention as duplicate "Update eclipse with Android Development tools 23",Already i was able to fix this issue.

Comment: This issue has been fixed.
Update your Android SDK Tool to 23.0.1
Check out this Link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24437564/update-eclipse-with-android-development-tools-23?answertab=active#tab-top