# adt bundle cannot launch after uninstall android developer tools accidently

Tags: adt

when I update android development tools 23 but have some errors like this: [Update Eclipse with Android development tools v. 23](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24437564/update-eclipse-with-android-development-tools-23)

and my ADT 23.0 was downloaded through browser on official site.
so I uninstall the pulgins manually but accidently uninstall the android developer tools, now I can't start my ADT Bundle again :( , anyone have some ideal to help me?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to just install the ADT installation part freshly.

Remove ADT first:

1. Open Install new software under help
2. Click Available Software Sites
3. Click the Android location
4. Click Remove

Install ADT freshly:

1. Open Install new software under help
2. Click Add
3. Name: type android
4. Location: copy this: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/
5. Click OK
6. Click the box near Developer Tools
7. Click Next
8. Click Next Again
9. Accept the agreement and click Next

This will install the ADT again!!!

Hope this helps!!