# android sdk ( 23 ) completely broken - where is an archive of 22.6?

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, adt

--EDIT--  see the comment for the missing archive

Made the mistake of downloading r23 of the sdk and now all ant,  CLI project builds are broken. Still on ant/eclipse do to NDK....

i have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24437564/update-eclipse-with-android-development-tools-23).

I know what state i want to get back to but am unable to find a 22.6 version of $SDK_ROOT/tools folder...

No [zipalign] .... its gone

No [proguard] .... its gone

oops. i dont have a backup of the tools directory and i can not seem to find older SDK downloads on the android sites ( all links point to r23 which is BROKEN )

example stdout from builds that worked yesterday on 22.6

```
-package:
[apkbuilder] Current build type is different than previous build: forced apkbuilder run.
[apkbuilder] Creating speech-debug-unaligned.apk and signing it with a debug key...

-post-package:

-do-debug:
 [zipalign] Running zip align on final apk...

BUILD FAILED
/home/rob/src/speech/build.xml:1113: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/rob/src/speech/build.xml:1115: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/rob/src/speech/build.xml:402: Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/usr/local/src/android-sdk-linux/tools/zipalign": java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:475)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:610)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute$Java13CommandLauncher.exec(Execute.java:862)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute.launch(Execute.java:481)
```

my sdk/tools below:

```
rob@ speech$ ls -l /usr/local/src/android-sdk-linux/tools
total 17368
-rwxr----- 1 rob rob    3498 Jun 23 13:11 android
drwxr-x--- 2 rob rob    4096 Jun 23 13:11 ant
drwxr-x--- 3 rob rob    4096 Jun 23 13:11 apps
-rwxr----- 1 rob rob    3286 Jun 23 13:11 ddms
-rwxr----- 1 rob rob    1940 Jun 23 13:11 draw9patch
-rwxr----- 1 rob rob   33428 Jun 23 13:11 emulator
-rwxr----- 1 rob rob 2854417 Jun 23 13:11 emulator64-arm
-rwxr----- 1 rob rob 2884527 Jun 23 13:11 emulator64-mips
-rwxr----- 1 rob rob 2956240 Jun 23 13:11 emulator64-x86
-rwxr----- 1 rob rob 2706541 Jun 23 13:11 emulator-arm
-rwxr----- 1 rob rob 2679855 Jun 23 13:11 emulator-mips
-rwxr----- 1 rob rob 2811534 Jun 23 13:11 emulator-x86
-rwxr----- 1 rob rob    3464 Jun 23 13:11 hierarchyviewer
-rwxr----- 1 rob rob    1845 Jun 23 13:11 jobb
drwxr-x--- 8 rob rob    4096 Jun 23 13:11 lib
-rwxr----- 1 rob rob    2046 Jun 23 13:11 lint
-rwxr----- 1 rob rob   12191 Jun 23 13:11 mksdcard
-rwxr----- 1 rob rob    1293 Jun 23 13:11 monitor
-rwxr----- 1 rob rob    3176 Jun 23 13:11 monkeyrunner
-rw-r----- 1 rob rob  758210 Jun 23 13:11 NOTICE.txt
-rwxr----- 1 rob rob    2259 Jun 23 13:11 screenshot2
-rw-r----- 1 rob rob      70 Jun 23 13:13 source.properties
drwxr-x--- 2 rob rob    4096 Jun 23 13:11 support
drwxr-x--- 6 rob rob    4096 Jun 23 13:11 templates
-rwxr----- 1 rob rob    3219 Jun 23 13:11 traceview
-rwxr----- 1 rob rob    3054 Jun 23 13:11 uiautomatorviewer
```

Comment: http://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r22.6.2-linux.tgz

has what i was look for ..

Comment: FYI - zipalign is in build tools 20 on my Windows machine. Once I downloaded the Windows equivalent of that tar file, zipalign was picked up OK by a command line Ant build.

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=72419

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem, but after updating to:

1. Android SDK Tools r23.0.2
2. Android SDK Platform-tools 20
3. Android SDK Build-tools 19.1

Issue was fixed.
For more info please look at "-build-setup" target in android build.xml(ANDROID_HOME\tools\ant\build.xml).

There you should see setting paths to zipalign tools:

```
    <target name="-build-setup" depends="-setup">
       <!-- find location of build tools -->
       <getbuildtools name="android.build.tools.dir" verbose="${verbose}" />
       <property name="aidl" location="${android.build.tools.dir}/aidl${exe}" />
       <property name="aapt" location="${android.build.tools.dir}/aapt${exe}" />
       <property name="dx" location="${android.build.tools.dir}/dx${bat}" />
       <property name="zipalign" location="${android.build.tools.dir}/zipalign${exe}" />
       ...
    </target>
```