# Eclipse and Android not working after updating tools to r23

Tags: android

I've updated my ADT to revision 23. There seems to be a bug in that release.
I would like to re-install everything and not install the r23.

I have saved my release keystore.

Is there anything else i need to back up before i wipe everything?

I have hosted one app on Google Play Store and several of our customers have it already. So it's important i do this properly or they won't be able to upgrade from a new keystore.

thanks in advance

Comment: as long as your workspace was separate - just reinstall eclipse then follow docs on the sdk/adt for their reinstall.. may have to download explicit sdk/adt releases from links to get level from R 23

Comment: @RobertRowntree sorry what do you mean as long as it is separate? my workspace is in a different folder to my eclipse?

Comment: like u say "diff folder for workspace" is OK to just reinstall all.

Comment: @RobertRowntree I have downloaded Eclipse Luna. I was using a previous version to this. I've clicked on help->Install New Software. I have gone to the following site ADT Plugin - https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ but the tools is r23. How can i install r22?

Comment: was a huge thread on SO bout a month ago .. let me look for it. in general , you have to do the steps by hand .. dwnload the version of SDK u need, downld the ADT version u need. do installs by hand in order to be on the back levels without R23.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24459303/android-sdk-23-completely-broken-where-is-an-archive-of-22-6

Comment: @RobertRowntree Thanks for your reply. I decided to delete eclipse Juno and the entire Android SDK. I have now downloaded Eclipse Luna and downloaded the Android SDK again. Everything seems to be ok. i have kept my original keystores, so there should be no problems publishing further releases of the app on the PlayStore. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to delete eclipse Juno and the entire Android SDK. I have now downloaded Eclipse Luna and downloaded the Android SDK again. Everything seems to be ok. i have kept my original keystores, so there should be no problems publishing further releases of the app on the PlayStore.