# Can't create activity through wizard with new Android SDK tools v23

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, adt

Today I updated Android SDK Tools to version 23, Android SDK platform-tools to version 20 and ADT Plugin. Everything works fine except one - I can't create an activity via wizard in any project. I point out all the necessary parameters, click "Finish" and nothing happens. Does anyone have the same issue? And maybe some of you already know how to solve it. Or should I just wait for an update from Google?

Comment: I have the same issue. Some of the earlier tools had this issue as well. You'd think they would have fixed this by now!

Comment: I have the same problem on my mac. When i start the wizard to create an activity end with message "The refactory does not change any source code".
The problems is the same if i download latest adt-bundle instead of update my adt plugin and sdk.
In addition when i create a new android project, the wizard don't create also the default package.
I have also added the missing files as suggested in https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=72419 and the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24437564/update-eclipse-with-android-development-tools-23 don't solve the problem.

Comment: Seems that the update at 23.0.1 solve some problem but creating a new project you can't add an activity and after creation do a manual refresh. The actual version is not stable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Google on June 27:

Please wait for an updated version within a day or two. Until then, your workaround is to do download one of:

See  the following for the full answer and suggestions:

```
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=72419
```

They say when you have opened the links provided in the answer, then copy over the following files:

```
tools/hprof-conv
tools/support/annotations.jar
tools/proguard
```