# ADT isn't working, launching Eclipse Juno instead

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I updated my ADT and SDK, installed a new JDK and now it open Eclipse Juno and not the Android Developpment Tool.

I installed these things:

- adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140624.zip
- jdk-8u5-windows-x64.exe

What can I do?

I also went to Eclipse - install new package according to the Google "Installing the ADT plugin guide" and it's still not working. Also, when I'm clicking the SDK manager - it doesn't open. It's opening a command prompt for 1 second.

Comment: related: [Update eclipse with Android Development tools 23](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24437564/update-eclipse-with-android-development-tools-23)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My English is not very good, so my words are translated from Google Translation. I have encountered such a problem before, I am a perfectionist, so can not tolerate this kind of thing, and now I have to solve this problem, Google has released the latest ADT-23.0.2, now at the following address.

win32: http://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140702.zip

win64: http://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702.zip

Copy the Eclipse folder to replace the original folder. Then create a file named ide.product file, copy the following into account:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?pde version="3.5"?>

<product name="Android Developer Tools" uid="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product" id="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product" application="org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench" version="23.0.2.qualifier" useFeatures="true" includeLaunchers="true">

<configIni use="default">
</configIni>

<launcherArgs>
  <programArgs>-product com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product</programArgs>
  <programArgsWin>--launcher.XXMaxPermSize 256M</programArgsWin>
  <vmArgs>-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6 -Xms40m -Xmx768m</vmArgs>
  <vmArgsLin>-XX:MaxPermSize=256m</vmArgsLin>
  <vmArgsMac>-XstartOnFirstThread -Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts</vmArgsMac>
  </launcherArgs>

  <windowImages/>

  <splash
  location="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package" />
  <launcher>
  <solaris/>
  <win useIco="true">
     <ico path="/plugin-adt-package/icons/adt.ico"/>
     <bmp/>
  </win>
  </launcher>

  <vm>
  <linux include="false">org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.6</linux>
  <macos include="false">org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.6</macos>
  <windows include="false">org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.6</windows>
  </vm>

  <plugins>
  </plugins>

  <features>
  <feature id="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package"/>
  </features>

  <configurations>
  <property name="eclipse.product" value="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product" />
  </configurations>

  </product>
```

However, after this start or juno interface, you can put the following path splash.bmp

```
C:\adt-bundle-windows-x86\eclipse\\plugins\org.eclipse.platform_4.2.1.v201209141800\splash.bmp
```

Replace the following path splash.bmp

```
C:\adt-bundle-windows-x86\eclipse\plugins\com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package_21.1.0.v201302060044-569685
```

As such you will be able to see you and then start a familiar interface.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html - only 20140624 is there. not 20140702

Comment: ADT's found a bug in the feedback page, which is the official personnel restored version, considered a transitional version, sorry, I forgot the specific website.

Comment: @DAvid - R u able to use latest ADT Bundle and ADT23.0.2 combination without any issues ? R u keeping your targetSDKVersion 20 in your applications and successfully develop those..? I'm curios to know..is that is the case..before putting all your recommendations on to my environment :)

Answer (score 1):

ADT is a plugin on top of Eclipse. So really, you can think of Eclipse being your IDE and ADT being the Android specific stuff. So it's perfectly normal for ADT to say Eclipse.

Also, when the SDK manager opens, it opens a command prompt at first and then opens the GUI. That's normal. However, if it doesn't open at all, try reinstalling the SDK.

Comment: the sdk is opening and the quit, and the eclipse isn't good like that, I add an eclipse says on start "android development tool" and in this eclipse there isn't and also in this eclipse I can't run my app on my lg g2, much things different.. its annoying me.. How can i get my old one back?

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here, using OSX. The downloaded ADB dows not show the typical ADB buttons and other extension provided by the plugins, but just a plain Eclipse. Installing an older version of ADT (adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140321) and updating won't help.

The package seemes somehow broken, some files like the ADT app icon, just aren't there. Other people experimented problems ([Same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24473212/latest-adt-bundle-open-as-juno-eclipse-for-windows-7-64-bit); [Other problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24437564/update-eclipse-with-android-development-tools-23), also documented [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=72419)).

I know it's not a real answer, but I just switched to Android Studio. I think the only other option is reverting to an older versione and wait for a new release.