# latest 'ADT BUNDLE' open as JUNO eclipse for windows 7 64 bit

Tags: adt

I downloaded the latest adt bundle (adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140624), and uncompresed that zip file, but when i try to open that adt, it open as juno eclipse. can any body help me to resolve this prblem.

thanks in advance

Comment: related: [Update eclipse with Android Development tools 23](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24437564/update-eclipse-with-android-development-tools-23)

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24466609/eclipse-adt-bundle-not-working-properly][1]

explains the current broken adt-bundle v23


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24466609/eclipse-adt-bundle-not-working-properly

Answer (score 1):

ADT Bundle contains Eclipse, to start Android development you need the ADT and the bundle comes with both you don't have to spend time searching for the ADT and Eclipse

Comment: thanks for quick reply. but earlier adt version having their own perspective this latest version this problem. little difficult to use this one.

Comment: Yes, I agree, it seems different, last night I had updated everything and then everything seemed different and the update broke all of my codes, still working to fix them

Comment: Are you trying to get to the Java perspective?

Comment: no. not like that, when create a new project it creates without /src/*.java & layout/.*xml files and also its icon also like undefined
application. welcome window open as juno. can i solve this, its difficult to work..

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here, using OSX. The downloaded ADB dows not show the typical ADB buttons and other extension provided by the plugins, but just a plain Eclipse. Installing an older version of ADT (adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140321) and updating won't help.

The package seemes somehow broken, some files like the ADT app icon, just aren't there. Other people experimented problems ([Same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24473212/latest-adt-bundle-open-as-juno-eclipse-for-windows-7-64-bit); [Other problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24437564/update-eclipse-with-android-development-tools-23), also documented [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=72419)).

I know it's not a real answer, but I just switched to Android Studio. I think the only other option is reverting to an older versione and wait for a new release.

Comment: thanks. I read their document (we have to wait the adt update). For my work having some conflict with Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

To not get blocked I've continued to install the latest ADT Bundle 23.0.0 and  adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140624 fresh on my system. Updated the SDK to the latest and continued to set "targetVersion as '19'" instead of setting it to 20 or 21.

That way you can proceed ahead with your coding and later when things get resolved...you can implement that to new version. BTW, I've also selected 'Blank Activity / Empty Activity" during the project creation

Comment back if it makes sense or NOT until the problem gets resolved by Google... :)

The Bug thread about this issue can be tracked here : [Latest ADT Bundle Bug Tracker](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=72419)