# MainActivity and Layout not being created?

Tags: android, eclipse

I am trying to create a new project and I am running into all kinds of issues and I am not sure why? I downloaded the SDK from developer.android.com, opened the SDK manager and downloaded the build tools for 19.1 and I have 20 installed (I think that is the new stuff Google just released). Then I opened Eclipse (I get Eclipse Juno splash page instead of android development tools splash page, not sure if this changed in the recent update?). Then I went to "Help" -> "Install new software" and installed from this url: dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse Finally I went to Help -> check for updates to make sure all of my stuff was up to date and no updates were found.

So I went to start a new project and selected the following:
1. New Android Application Project
2. Selected API 19 4.4 KitKat for Minimum, target and compile with SDK.
3. Theme Holo Light
4. Uncheck create custom launcher
5. Make sure create activity IS checked, everything else left alone
6.  Create activity checked on next screen and selected Blank Activity
7. Activity Name and Layout Name left as defaults.
8. Click finish.. and no MainActivity.java is created my src folder is empty?!f

Comment: possible duplicate of [Update eclipse with Android Development tools 23](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24437564/update-eclipse-with-android-development-tools-23)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you to go back to the ADT bundle before this one, here is a place you can download from :

https://dl.google.com/android/adt/22.6.2/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140321.zip

I had the same problem like you, its a problem in the new ADT .. install this one until google will fix it in a new version.

Comment: I installed this version but now windows is giving me a "This app cannot be run on your PC". Is that link to a 64-bit version? I have a 32-bit system. Do you have another link?

Comment: I played with the URL and found: https://dl.google.com/android/adt/22.6.2/adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140321.zip downloading and installing now..

Comment: When I used the 32-bit version it worked! Seems like the new ADT bundle has a bunch of issues and is best to stay away from for now. Thanks so much for your assistance.

Comment: No problem :) i am sorry I didn't see your comments, only now.. The link was for 64 bit ..

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing this problem, but i figured out. I choosed `Empty Activity` in step 6 instead of `Blank Activity`, rest of steps are same as yours.

```
1. New Android Application Project 
2. Selected API 19 4.4 KitKat for Minimum, target and compile with SDK. 
3. Theme Holo Light 
4. Uncheck create custom launcher 
5. Make sure create activity IS checked, everything else left alone 
6. Create activity checked on next screen and selected Empty Activity 
7. Activity Name and Layout Name left as defaults. 
8. Click finish..
```

I hope this will work for you too.