# What is the definitive meaning of "Requesting resource failed because it is complex" in Android?

Tags: android

This exception message has been reported widely, but it is never mentioned in any of Android's official documentations.

I do not have any code to show, because it is sporadic and so far I cannot find any patterns as to what causes it to happen.

Comment: I can't find that string or its parts in the Android source code.  It looks like a complex resource is something with multiple possible values, like a state list.

Comment: (I'm voting to close my own question. More information will be coming soon.) - **For those who have not yet updated the Android SDK and Eclipse ADT in the past week, do so NOW and [also pay attention to the latest news on this post (linked)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24437564/update-eclipse-with-android-development-tools-23).**

Answer (score 3):

I passed an array.resourceId instead of a drawable/resourceId and i got a similar error. I would check that.

Comment: Same. I got the same error when passing a string-array instead of a single drawable or resourceId.