# Eclipse Adt Plugin Doesn't Work

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I can't install the adt plugin for eclipse.It says "Plugin is already installed" but I can't use.

Here you can see:http://prntscr.com/3zbzi4

Ps:Also I can't delete the plugin it's giving error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this problem.

1)Uninstalled adt bundle then downloaded latest version.

2)Downloaded latest eclipse standart from eclipse site

3)Opened eclipse standart and changed workspace to C:\users....\workspace2

4)Installed latest ADT plugin from Help->Install New Software

And problem is resolved.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem once i updated versions via SDK manager. It required ADT version 23.0 and above, and couldn't install them via install new software. I managed to delete ADT but that couldn't launch eclipse after to download v23.0.

I solved my problem via downloading lastest version of bundle from site.
http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

P.S. Try de-selecting Android Hierarchy Viewer and install rest. If others also cause similar problem, re-installing will probably be simpler option

Comment: I already reinstalled latest version of bundle.It not resolved my problem.

Comment: If you are using lastest bundle, why do you need to update tools ? Its lastest versions on last bundle as far as i know.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, and the only way I could get it to work again was to reinstall eclipse.

So I installed the latest eclipse, bundled together with ADT, works great.

I couldn't find the bundle maybe it doesn't exist anymore, but still, it's a bad answer i know, but reinstall works :/

Found the link: http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Answer (score 0):

My experience is that if you have installed or updated the SDK then your ADT may not be compatible with your updated SDK.

For example -

When I installed 23.0.0, it wasn't installed because of dependencies,

> **ADT 23.0.0 (June 2014)**
>
> *Dependencies:*
>
> - Java 7 or higher is required if you are targeting the L Developer    Preview.
> - Java 1.6 or higher is required if you are targeting other releases.
> - Eclipse Indigo (Version 3.7.2) or higher is required.
> - This version of ADT is designed for use with SDK Tools r23.0.0. If    you haven't already installed SDK Tools r23.0.0 into your SDK, use
>     the Android SDK Manager to do so.

SOURCE: http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html

Also, many problems were solved by doing the following steps for the **ADT 23.0.2** -

[update-eclipse-with-android-development-tools-23](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24437564/update-eclipse-with-android-development-tools-23).

Comment: I am using latest version of sdk.I still have this problem.

Comment: @TolgayToklar - Latest version of sdk isn't the surity for proper install of ADT 23.0.2. Check compatibility of both.

Answer (score 0):

I had this as well after upgrading the SDK manager and build tools etc.

I had to remove Eclipse from my PC and then re-download a fresh copy of the Eclipse and ADT Bundle from http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html