# ADT eclipse GUI problems

Tags: android, eclipse, user-interface, adt

It doesn't fully load the GUI, I can't create new layouts. It doesn't generate any source files, even when I create a new activity. I have downloaded it several times, but I can't get it fully working. I've used eclipse before, I'm no stranger to it. The ADT I downloaded bugs as hell. I tried 32&64 bit, both didn't work. [Here is a link to the ADT](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#download)

[image: picture]

Answer (score 0):

To unhide a menu item or toolbar button:

1. Switch to the perspective that you want to configure.
2. Select  command link Window > Customize Perspective....
3. Open the Menu Visibility or Tool Bar Visibility tab.
4. Find the item you want to hide. You can do this two ways:
   Expand the menu or toolbar hierarchy to find the item you want to hide.
   Click the Filter by command group check box to see a list of command groups which contribute items, and choose the command group the item you wish to hide. Then navigate to the item in the hierarchy in the Structure tree.
5. Hover over the item to get additional information:
   a description of what the item does
   the name of the command group which contributes the item (click the link in this item to switch to the Command Groups Availability tab with the appropriate command group selected).
   any key bindings associated with the command the item performs (click the link in this item to open the Keys page of the Preferences dialog with the command selected, if possible).
   if the item is dynamic, a preview of its current appearance (dynamic items are listed as [Dynamic]).
6. Check the check box next to the item. Uncheck a menu to hide all its children.
7. Click OK to cause the changes to take effect.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't change a thing.

Comment: It still doesn't fully work, I can see some icons now. But the program icon, in the upper left corner is still blank. Can't I download an older version?

Answer (score 0):

There are indeed some very annoying bugs in the latest ADT. I had the exact same problem. The simple solution would be to manually update your ADT plugins from Eclipse, but unfortunately, it's not so easy for most people. You can find all of the solutions (and solutions to the failed solutions) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24437564/update-eclipse-with-android-development-tools-23).

If you don't want to try solution after solution, just do what I did and download Eclipse Juno, the ADT plugins and the SDK separately. If it's still not creating files or if it's giving you errors, you may have to clean the workspace and/or import some jar files.