# android sdk rev 23 requires ATD 23 using eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt, android-sdk-2.3

i'm using eclipse, after updated android `SDK` (rev = 23) here my problems started.

so `SDK` (rev = 23) requires ATD 23 okay no problem so simply i go to **Help > Install new software** next it feels like i successfully did updated  ADT to 23 but same **error** still there **SDK requires ATD 23 or above** then i ckeck ADT version it's still old version

[image]

still 22.3!!!

[image]

okay i will try again to update **Help > Install new software** but it's feels it won't allow me to do that because it is already installed!! **`what!!`**.

[image]

Details :

```
Cannot complete the request.  See the error log for details.
"Android Traceview" will be ignored because it is already installed.
"Android Development Tools" will be ignored because it is already installed.
"Android DDMS" will be ignored because it is already installed.
"Android Hierarchy Viewer" will be ignored because it is already installed.
"Android Native Development Tools" will be ignored because it is already installed.
"Tracer for OpenGL ES" will be ignored because it is already installed.
```

**Note** : Added missing file to My SDK (this issues was reported) [here on code google](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=72419):

it's seems this question already asked but i couldn't fix my problem i checked this qustion :

1-[Update Eclipse with Android development tools v. 23](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24437564/update-eclipse-with-android-development-tools-23)

i hope anyone know how to fix my problem Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not the only one have problems in this version, you can wait to someone will try to solve it to you but it's really hard, it happened to me too and it's a problem of google.

I recommend you to go back to the ADT bundle before this one there are problems right now, here is a place you can download from :

https://dl.google.com/android/adt/22.6.2/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140321.zip - Windows 7 64 bit https://dl.google.com/android/adt/22.6.2/adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140321.zip - Windows 7 32 bit

I had the same problem like you, its a problem in the new ADT .. install this one until google will fix it in a new version.

Comment: Thanks i just downloaded new ADT then link my sdk to.