# src and layout folder empty in android [Installing new software solution does not work for conflicting dependencies]

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

When i create an Android Appliaction Project in Eclipse, the eclipse was supposed to generate MainActivity.java in the src folder and activity_main.xml in the layout folder. But These two folders are empty. I have searched the internet and saw it was a common issue and the sugested solution is **Help-->Install new software** but that doesnt work for me as for some conflicting dependencies. I have recently downloaded the ADT. My current version is 23.0 .

Now what do i do? Please suggest something.

Comment: Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24437564/update-eclipse-with-android-development-tools-23

Comment: Its really depressing. Ended up with downloading the whole bundle again.