# Android Eclipse - Cannot see annotation processing option

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-annotations

I am unable to fine the option to set annotation processing in my Eclipse preferences. [image]

Not sure since when am I getting this problem but surely it has started to occur after I updated eclipse last. 
I also tried pasting the annotations.jar file in tools/support folder but to no good.

Kindly help.

TIA

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Installing

> Programming Languages > Eclipse Java Development Tools

may enable it again.

[image]

Comment: This worked for me on Mac. Good synthesis for valuable information following link "Try This" given by Big O. Thanks.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Then you don't have to reinstall Eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

It seems Google removed the Annotation Processor option from project properties in the ADT bundle. We are tracking the problem in [this](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/issues/1066) AndroidAnnotations issue. The current workaround for this is not installing the bundle, but downloading a standalone Eclipse distribution and adding the ADT plugin to that.

Comment: @WonderCsabo Your answer is based on same issue I linked in my answer. It's part of ADT 23 problem.

Comment: Thanks, Downloaded the non-bundled Eclipse. Am back to work now... Cheers mate!!

Answer (score 2):

Updating Eclipse Java Development Tools worked for me. 
[Try This](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/issues/1066#issuecomment-49600888)

Answer (score 0):

If annotations.jar is missing, it maybe ADT 23 related problems.
Check this.

[Update eclipse with Android Development tools 23](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24437564/update-eclipse-with-android-development-tools-23#)

> Google response:
>   ...
>   and copy over the following files:
>
> > tools/hprof-conv
> >     tools/support/annotations.jar
> >     tools/proguard

---

(Added)
If its ADT bundle problem (part of ADT 23 related problem),
this part is for you. (Linked above)

> Google response:
>   ...
>   This is a packaging bug. The entire proguard file is missing. We'll have an update asap, but until then just copy it over from a previous version of the tools:
>   ...
>   Edit: with the latest ADT release, the bundle should now work with auto-update, so install these new versions:
>
> linux 64 bit vm: http://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140702.zip
>      linux 32 bit vm: http://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-linux-x86-20140702.zip
>      mac: http://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702.zip
>      win32: http://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140702.zip
>      win64: http://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702.zip
>
> Don't try to upgrade from previous version because it doensn't work at all. If you have got problems with zipalign, it's now under platform-tools and no more under tools/ so you can do a symbolic link or just copy it into the expected folder.

or use "not-bundled" Eclipse.

---

ADT23 problem related links
[Issue 72400 (merged into 72419)](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=72400) getDefaultProguardFile no longer returns valid path using build SDK tools 23
[Issue 72419](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=72419) Proguard not installed with SDK tools rev. 23

Comment: This has nothing to do with the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Copied APTDemo.jar from http://www.eclipse.org/jdt/apt/APTDemo.jar in the lib folder and I can see the  option in my compiler preferences. I will investigate later, fixed my problem for now.