# Android stop button animation on an event

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

Android stop button animation on an event

I am trying to animate a button. The animation is working but I am not able to stop it.

First I defined a property in the class

```
private ObjectAnimator animatorBtn;
```

Then when an event ocur inside a method I start the animation

```
@Override
public void writeMessage(final Message message) {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (myBtn.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE && messageView.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE) {
                myBtn.setBackground(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.red_round_button));
                animatorBtn = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(myBtn, "translationY", -100f, 0f);
                animatorBtn.setDuration(1000);//1sec
                animatorBtn.setInterpolator(new BounceInterpolator());
                animatorBtn.setRepeatCount(ValueAnimator.INFINITE);
                animatorBtn.start();
            }
            messageView.writeViewMessage(message);
        }
    });
}
```

On another event I am trying to stop it. but is not working

```
@OnClick(R.id.my_btn)
void onClickMyBtn() {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            myBtn.setBackground(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.green_round_button));
            if (animatorBtn != null) {
                animatorBtn.cancel();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

thank you

Comment: Worked fine for me. Are you sure that cancel is being called?

Comment: Thank you @Whitney, I am sure that the cancel is being called because I am also debugging it.

Comment: Can the trigger event happen more than once before the cancel event?

Comment: I checked for that but is only called once. In the logcat I saw this Skipped 108 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread. maybe is related with that. thank you @Whitney

Comment: Try animatorBtn.clearAnimation();

Comment: @AHoneyBustard thank you, I tried but didn't work neither.

Comment: Also I tried animatorBtn.setRepeatCount(0); and is not working

Comment: Can you post more code?

Comment: @Whitney I posted more code, thank you

Comment: I see you are using ButterKnife. So you have set up the project like so correct: http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/ide-eclipse.html

Comment: @Whitney thank you, I am using Butterknife with Android Studio. I didn't find configuration for that. But I will try to binding that button without butterknife.

Comment: To see those configuration items, I followed the answer here (the one upvoted 18 times, not the accepted answer): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24724866/android-eclipse-cannot-see-annotation-processing-option