# How to solve dependecy issues in eclipse ide for ADT updation?

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I updated my sdk version to 23, and when i restarted the adt.

[Got This Msg] (http://cdn.imghack.se/images/fd8b7e0f3004f32b440b1b11f1afc1fa.jpg)  //No reputation

And When I checked for updates nothing was found. I searched here(stackoverflow), got a suggestion to installing ADT again.

So, I did try that. And stopped by another error.

```
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
 Software being installed: Android Development Tools 23.0.2.1259578 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.feature.group 23.0.2.1259578)
 Software currently installed: Android Developer Tools 22.6.2.v201403212031-1085508 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product 22.6.2.v201403212031-1085508)
 Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
   ADT XML Overlay 23.0.2.1259578 (overlay.com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.overlay 23.0.2.1259578)
   ADT XML Overlay 22.6.2.v201403212031-1085508 (overlay.com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.overlay 22.6.2.v201403212031-1085508)
Cannot satisfy dependency:
  From: Android Development Tools 23.0.2.1259578 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.feature.group 23.0.2.1259578)
  To: overlay.com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.overlay [23.0.2.1259578]
Cannot satisfy dependency:
  From: Android Development Tools 22.6.2.v201403212031-1085508 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 22.6.2.v201403212031-1085508)
  To: overlay.com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.overlay [22.6.2.v201403212031-1085508]
Cannot satisfy dependency:
  From: ADT Package 22.6.2.v201403212031-1085508 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.feature.group 22.6.2.v201403212031-1085508)
  To: com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 22.6.2
Cannot satisfy dependency:
  From: Android Developer Tools 22.6.2.v201403212031-1085508 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product 22.6.2.v201403212031-1085508)
  To: com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.feature.group [22.6.2.v201403212031-1085508]
```

Help Out!!

Comment: It seems ADT23 problem. Check this.[Update eclipse with Android Development tools 23](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24437564/update-eclipse-with-android-development-tools-23#)

Comment: It worked out.. I had to copy the whole sdk/tools folder from the old version.

Comment: There is a new issue in graphical layout.(This version of the rendering library is more recent than your version of ADT plug-in. Please update ADT plug-in). and i can't update adt because of this dependency issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolved!

```
Go to help-->about eclipse-->Installation details
A new window will appear "Eclipse installation details" under "Installed Software" Tab select plugins which you want to uninstall it.  
Android DDMS, Android Development Tools(ADT) and etc.

Go to install new software and using the link:
url : https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ install them!
```

Worked fine for me :)

Comment: Seems to be exactly right...but i can't find tht option of uninstalling ddms and adt etc. because.. i'm getting help--about ADT.

Comment: Hi for clear understanding I have edited my post. If it resolve your issue then please don't forget to accept my answer. :)