# Android Bundle ADT update issue

Tags: android, eclipse, ide, adt

We faced a lot of problems like plugin conflicts while updating our ADT from 22 to 23. After struggling a lot we updated the ADT to 23. But when we try to set the SDK location under  "Preferences" we are getting following error message "This Android SDK requires ADT version 23.0 or above. Please update ADT to the latest version" . But we updated the version to 23. What we guess is in some configuration file the update information is not reflected. Attaching the screen shot which displays the version of ADT[image]. In which config file we have to update the information ? What could be the best solution for this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

Try updating the ADT Plugin

Select Help > Install New Software

Work with: p2repo - https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

Select Developer Tools and Next
Next, Accept the license agreement* and Finish

**refer: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/24437737/3518278**

Comment: Didn't resolve the issue. Still not able to set the sdk path.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem what i did i downloaded the latest adt bundle. Because if u would try to install the softwares then there can be some conflicting issues, after that you can set the sdk path in  preferences.

Try that .

Answer (score 0):

i had same issue while updating my ADT,
For updation ADT:23 u need to install jdk version:1.7 and up.
Hope it helps u as well :)