# Android SDK- Eclipse ADT Plugin - dependency conflict

Tags: android, eclipse-plugin, adt

```
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.


 Software being installed: Android Traceview 23.0.3.1327240 (com.android.ide.eclipse.traceview.feature.feature.group 23.0.3.1327240)

  Software currently installed: Android Developer Tools 22.0.1.v201305230001--685705 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product 22.0.1.v201305230001--685705)

 Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    Traceview 23.0.3.1327240 (com.android.ide.eclipse.traceview 23.0.3.1327240)
    Traceview 22.3.0.v201310242005-887826 (com.android.ide.eclipse.traceview 22.3.0.v201310242005-887826)


 Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: ADT Package 22.0.1.v201305230001--685705 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.feature.group 22.0.1.v201305230001--685705)
    To: com.android.ide.eclipse.traceview.feature.group 22.0.0


Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Android Developer Tools 22.0.1.v201305230001--685705 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product 22.0.1.v201305230001--685705)
    To: com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.feature.group [22.0.1.v201305230001--685705]

Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Android Traceview 23.0.3.1327240 (com.android.ide.eclipse.traceview.feature.feature.group 23.0.3.1327240)
    To: com.android.ide.eclipse.traceview [23.0.3.1327240]

Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Android Traceview 22.3.0.v201310242005-887826 (com.android.ide.eclipse.traceview.feature.group 22.3.0.v201310242005-887826)
    To: com.android.ide.eclipse.traceview [22.3.0.v201310242005-887826]
```

How can I solve this conflict?

p.s. I tried help-> check for updates but it says no updates found!! I am using eclipse from sdk package. (C:\Program Files (x86)\Android SDK\eclipse)

I have eclipse luna installed at other location which I use for Java development. It also has adt plugin installed (latest one)

pps: I have deleted the eclipse folder from location (C:\Program Files (x86)\Android SDK\eclipse)  and replace it with new one from adt bundle and then downloaded adt plugin..
so things are fine now

Comment: First you need to update your Eclipse with `Kepler` then you should update your `ADT` with `23.0` in that way i updated my `ADT` with `23.0` successfully..

Comment: I tried help-> check for updates but it says no updates found!! I am using eclipse from sdk package. (C:\Program Files (x86)\Android SDK\eclipse)

how can I update it to kepler.. I have eclipse luna installed at other location which I used for Java development. It also has adt plugin installed (latest one)

Comment: Go to `Help-->Install New Software`--> `and select Kepler - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/kepler` and download updates....

Comment: I tried, I also tried to update everything - adt plugin, android developers tools update site, juno, eclipse project update, kepler. Then I get following message:

Cannot complete the install because some dependencies are not satisfiable
  org.eclipse.actf.visualization.sdk.feature.group [1.1.0.R201306091406] cannot be installed in this environment because its filter is not applicable.

Comment: @Nikhil i have same problem. did you resolved you issue??

Comment: Yes  I have deleted the eclipse folder from location (C:\Program Files (x86)\Android SDK\eclipse) and replace it with latest one from adt bundle and then downloaded adt plugin.. so things are fine now

but before that you can try to all those steps mentioned. go to Help-->Install New Software-update everything  adt plugin, android developers tools update site, juno, eclipse project update, kepler.

Comment: For anyone else with the problem: It's possible to resolve it without deleting everything: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24437564/update-eclipse-with-android-development-tools-v-23