# Cannot Update ADT For Eclipse Adt Bundle

Tags: android

I am Using ADT Bundle But when i update my sdk and restart eclipse it shows the following Error. I tried many options to resolve this like update adt from help>install new software.Also manually download ADT Plugin 23.0.3 and tried to install from localhost But my issue cannot be resolved.Please help me with this issue.

Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: Android Traceview 23.0.3.1327240 (com.android.ide.eclipse.traceview.feature.feature.group 23.0.3.1327240)

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24437564/update-eclipse-with-android-development-tools-v-23?rq=1