# eclipse ADT nightmare

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

It's September 25, 2014 and I am in the middle of this Google nightmare:

[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24437564/update-eclipse-with-android-development-tools-v-23)

I read about 40 solutions that don't work.  I'm dead in the water.  Did anyone ever come up with a solution?
Thanks,
Dean

Comment: only soln,download a fresh copy from http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Update Eclipse with Android development tools v. 23](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24437564/update-eclipse-with-android-development-tools-v-23)

Comment: Krylez: the link you and the forum moderator refer to is my HERE link.

Comment: kgandroid: Yep, started over and 6 hours later it looks like I can once again build my projects.  The google master is soooo cruel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the record, kgandroid was right.  I had to wipe everything out and re download the ADTBundle (making sure everything was in the same place), reinstall Eclipse, and reinstall the sdk libraries.

Maybe I'll give Android Studio a try if it ever comes out of beta.

I'm still not sure what caused it.
Dean