# In switch to Android Studio should my SDK location be the same as Eclipse version?

Tags: eclipse, sdk, android-ndk, android-studio, adt

I'm trying to move from Eclipse ADT NDK build to Android Studio on my Mac OS X.  In doing this, one thing I notice is the Project Structure's Android SDK Location for my ported project and for new projects is defaulting to be: `/Users/user1/Development/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20131030/sdk`.

Shouldn't the Android Studio come with its own SDK and shouldn't I be using it by default?  I looked in the application install directory but found no signs of an SDK directory there.  I'm concerned that the sdk is from October 30, 2013 and so it seems rather old.  What are the implications of moving to a newer SDK?

---

<s>Perhaps related to this is that when trying to use the old Eclipse Kepler that used to build for me:</s>

I get notice on Eclipse launch:

```
This Android SDK requires Android Developer Toolkit version 23.0.0 or above.
Current version is 22.6.2.v2014032112031-1085508.
Please update ADT to the latest version.
```

Click "Check for Updates":

```
No Updates were found.

No Repository found at https://dl.google.com/alt.
```

Tried to update the repository to (for Kepler Eclipse):

```
https://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/4.3
```

Still no updates found but error about no repository goes away.

I **resolved this later issue** with the [answer posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24437737/115751).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cant comment on details of OSX but on linux/AS with Eclipse & AS , i found follow to help:

provision environment to use multiple versions of java JDK

install oracle JDK 1.7 that will be just for use by shell script running AS

note ASRoot/bin/studio.sh .... if [ -n "$STUDIO_JDK"

accordingly provide for the above ENV VAR and its use by the AS.studio.sh

that version of the JDK does nothing more than run AS

Then , for the ADT stuff (OK to be shared by Eclipse & AS ), you can keep updated another version of the SDK/ADT in a path where theres read access by both eclipse/ AS.

I think u can use ./android to keep updated this , original sdk/adt