# Android SDK requires ADT version 23.0.0

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm getting error whenever I open eclipse and that error is

> Android SDK requires ANDROID DEVELOPMENT TOOLKIT version 23.0.0 or
>   above

Current version is 22. I tried to follow these steps:

- Select Help > Install New Software
- work with: `p2repo` - https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/
- Select Developer Tools and Next
- Next, Accept the license agreement
- and Finish

but I am getting an error which is conflicting dependency.
Here is a picture:

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24437564/update-eclipse-with-android-development-tools-v-23/24437737#24437737

Comment: Duplicated question and you should switch to Android Studio.