# The project target (Android 5.0.1) was not properly loaded

Tags: java, android, eclipse, ide

I just updated my SDK to 5.0.1 and as i restarted the IDE and then came across this error statement. This comes when i open the activity xml. The UI in it does not load. I tried deleting the SDK folder and then again updating it but still got that error. I am really unable to see the UI in the 5.0.1 api. I tried restarting the PC and again setting the JAVA_HOME but still didn't work. I am using Ubuntu 12.04 32 bit. I am not sure what i am missing. Any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: You probably have to update your adt as well. 

[Update adt in Eclipse][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24437564/update-eclipse-with-android-development-tools-v-23

Comment: the update was done perfectly and now it has resolved many of my other similar errors but still this one persists..

Answer (score 6):

If you're using Eclipse, then go to the graphical layout page of an XML layout file and look near the top where you see the dropdown menus of what device you can use or what orientation your app will be in. (landscape or portrait) There should be a dropdown with the Android logo that lets you select the API to use.  Be sure that 19 or lower is selected.

Answer (score 0):

Selected API 20 instead of 21, and it worked.