# is there a way to open a LibGDX project without the SDK?

Tags: java, eclipse, libgdx

i want to open a LibGDX project but it makes me put the location of the SDK. i have the SDK but it gives me bugs (look at this post i did, maybe you can help also there [bugs in eclipse after installing LibGDX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28283193/bugs-in-eclipse-after-installing-libgdx)) and it is uncomftorable to use. so is there a way to use my phone without giving it the location of the SDK?

btw i'm working with eclipse.

Comment: Don't use Eclipse for LibGDX anymore. It is not supported. Import into Android Studio.

Comment: what does that mean? i want to make a game not an app.

Comment: Of course. This is why you must use Android Studio. It has better `Gradle` integration, the new build system that replaced `ant`. The latest `LibGDX` releases do not support Eclipse ADT anymore.

Comment: Also, considering you're making a game for Android, you'll need the Android SDK, and the proper build tools. Last time I checked it needed `19.1.0` but I think it's probably been updated since then as that was a few months ago.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce do you have a link, where they say, that Eclipse is not supported anymore? The wiki stil shows how to set it up using Eclispe and also in the news i did not find a post which says Eclipse is not supported anymore.

Comment: @Springrbua Okay, I guess I went a bit ahead of myself. Last time I tried to get `LibGDX` working with the `Gradle` plugin that's available for Eclipse, it worked with LibGDX 1.2, but not with LibGDX 1.3 (or a newer version.. it's been a while) no matter what I tried. In fact, I even answered that here when even for LibGDX 1.2 it was not trivial: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25243615/libgdx-1-3-0-doesnt-build-eclipse-files/25246284#25246284

Comment: @EpicPandaForce i worked with libgdx in eclipse not long time ago, as much as i remember it was a 1.4.x Version and it worked perfectly. But i have to say, that i worked on a Desktop-Only Game, so i did not use the Android SDK.

Comment: so not to use android studio? i would prefer to use eclipse since i already have it. and if i can use eclipse how can i fix the errors and use my own phone? again, you can see what bugs i have here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28283193/bugs-in-eclipse-after-installing-libgdx

Comment: @Springrbua hmm.. Fair enough. Well, I still recommend Android Studio. It's much easier to get it working with. And now that it's over `1.0.0`, there's honestly no really good reason not to use it.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce i don't know AndroidStudio, so i can't compare it to Eclipse, but if Libgdx stil works with Eclipse (again, i had no problems, creating a Project with the Libgdx Setup UI), i see no reason to switch IDE.

Comment: @Springrbua apart from that Android Studio is now the official IDE for Android development, Eclipse ADT is no longer updated, and also that Android Studio has better Gradle integration which LibGDX uses heavily?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce well, i have to try out how good Eclipse works with Android, if there are bugs or other things it may be worth switching to AndroidStudio, but if there aren't any bigger problems, i guess it isn't a bad idea to stay with Eclipse.

Comment: @Springrbua this really feels like a discussion about whether it's still worth it to still use Windows XP even though it's no longer officially supported.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce i wouldn't compare Eclipse with Windows XP, Eclipse itself is still supported and updated, while XP hast been replaced by newer OS. Even the Libgdx Wiki stil shows how to set up a project using Eclipse, IntelliJ and NetBeans, while i coulnd't find an article about AndroidStudio. So i guess currently Eclipse should still do the Job and for me it isn't worth switching. Just my opinion.

Comment: @Springrbua Well this ended up lengthy ^_^ anyways, he does need the Android SDK to use LibGDX, that's the answer.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce you are right, enough off-topic-discussion :D Anyways, thanks for telling me, that Eclipse ADT is not updated anymore. I may take a look at AndroidStudio. At topic: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Setting-up-your-Development-Environment-%28Eclipse%2C-Intellij-IDEA%2C-NetBeans%29 may help...

Comment: @Springrbua I had these issues with project setup in Eclipse ALL THE TIME, and once I switched they all went away. I was reluctant to switch because I already was familiar with Eclipse, but now I'm kicking myself that I didn't do it sooner. It is trivial to learn a new IDE. Even it if saves you a single episode of *project setup nightmare* it's worth it to switch. Your life will be better, I guarantee it. By the way, Android Studio is basically just Intellij with features added, so all the wki instructions for Intellij apply.

Comment: @Tenfour04 thanks for sharing your experience. If i decide to start another project, i will give Eclipse a last try. If i face the same problems (again, i never used android SDK and without android SDK i never had any problems) i will try out AndroidStudio. Thanks!