# Android SDK requires ADT version 23 or above

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova, adt

I was working on a project in Eclipse and unfortunately I removed some of my files and wasn't able to retrieve them back so I ended up creating a new project and importing my files back in. When this happened, I now receive an error:

[image]

When I try and update, it says it's already updated. I'm receiving multiple compilation errors in my project and am not sure what is going on since everything was working before I removed my files.

[image]

I see that it is telling me DDMS files are not found.. is this due to it not picking up my SDK? I tried to Help -> Install New Software and do a ADT but it seems I have already installed this since everything was working before.

[image]

Help on this issue on how to proceed/fix would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You seem to have a conflict, see this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24437564/update-eclipse-with-android-development-tools-v-23

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that eclipse has edited or deleted files when updating

follow steps for updating eclipse

```
 1. Download Eclipse from the official site
 2. Download and install JDK latest version
 3. After installing the eclipse, go to Help > Install New Software.
 4. Click Add, in the top-right corner.
 5. In the Add Repository dialog that appears, enter "ADT Plugin" for the
Name and the following URL for the Location: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/
Click OK.
 6. In the Available Software dialog, select the checkbox next to Developer Tools and click Next.
 7. In the next window, you'll see a list of the tools to be downloaded. Click Next.
 8. Read and accept the license agreements, then click Finish.If you get a security warning saying that the authenticity or validity of the software can't be established, click OK.
 9. When the installation completes, restart Eclipse.
```