# TransformerException: Premature end of file error

Tags: java, xslt, xml-parsing, jaxb, java-stream

I am trying to generate outFile base on the marshalled xml and xslt and some issue.

Piece of code produces xml stream from object.

```
 JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(EmployeeFormat.class);
 ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
 Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
 marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);         
 marshaller.marshal(employeeFormat,os);
 outEmpFile(new ByteArrayInputStream(os.toByteArray()));
```

This method produces the outFile taking the xml as input

```
public void outEmpFile(ByteArrayInputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
    File template = new File("C/workspace/files/Employee.xslt"); 
    File outFile = new File(C:/workspace/files/Employee.java");

    TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer(new StreamSource(template));             
    transformer.transform(new StreamSource(inputStream),new StreamResult(outFile));
}
```

I get TransformerException when running the code :

```
 ERROR:  'Premature end of file.'javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: 

  com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.utils.WrappedRuntimeException: Premature end of file.
```

Both input xml and xslt produces expected output in online tool - http://www.utilities-online.info/xsltransformation.

This code gives the correct xml file in console.

```
public void  byteToString(ByteArrayInputStream is) {       
    int size = is.available();
    char[] theChars = new char[size];
    byte[] bytes    = new byte[size];

 is.read(bytes, 0, size);
    for (int i = 0; i < size;)
        theChars[i] = (char)(bytes[i++]&0xff);

    System.out.println("Xml String :"+ new String(theChars));
  }
```

Any help on the issue please?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the inputstream is consumed before passing in transform method which resulted in Premature end of file error.
Refer this for more info - [org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Premature end of file for *VALID* XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11114665/org-xml-sax-saxparseexception-premature-end-of-file-for-valid-xml)